# The Power of Teams: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, old-teams, announcement

## Update

A follow-up to this post has been made here: ["The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions)

---

## TL;DR:

We're proposing a new area called **Teams.** The goal is to allow groups (of varying sizes) to publicly share about themselves (who they are and what they build) on Stack Overflow. Content can include information about The Team (Overview, Meta Information), a member roster, projects, community interaction (Questions), and recruitment (Jobs, Get Involved). Team affiliations will be reflected in your user profile.

---

This past spring, the product team held a multi-week brainstorming session where we thought about how we could build on [Stack Overflow's current success of improving the lives of developers.](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) What other valuable information does the programming community need, but is trapped elsewhere online and offline?

[**Documentation**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) is one of those ideas. **Teams** is another, and that’s what we’re excited to share with you today.

## Huh? Teams?

First let me state what Teams are and why we’re excited about them:

**Teams are a new way to share your knowledge with the world.** This includes what you build, who you build it with, answers to questions about how you build it, and how others can get involved. These groups can vary in size from a few people working on a small open-source project to companies and sub-teams within those companies.

**Here’s why we’re excited about teams:**

1. Teams allow for a new kind of Q&A that wouldn’t be allowed right now
2. Teams let you show off more of what you do professionally
3. Teams help you hire developers or recruit for your open source project

[image: Teams Mockup]

## How does adding Teams to Stack Overflow solve this?

**It introduces a new kind of Q&A.**

Teams addresses a need the community wanted solved from the beginning, but didn’t fit in our original Q&A. Documentation is our attempt to help the community address questions which would typically be considered too broad. ***Teams is our attempt to address items which typically are considered too localized.***

What do we mean by "too localized"? Well, let’s start off with what we *don’t* mean. Questions such as "please fix my codes" **will still not be allowed**. Instead, we’re looking to provide a place for questions such as:

- "How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?",
- "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?", or
- "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?"

These are interesting questions which don’t have room in the community right now. These questions allow us to start sharing how various teams have arrived at solutions others can learn from.

**It lets you show off more of what you do professionally.**

[image: XKCD: No I in Team]

Your user profile lets you show off your own achievements: what you have done on Stack Overflow, who you are, how you’re involved. Teams are an extension of your profile by letting you now share about your team, what you’re building, who’s working on it with you, how you’re solving problems, and how people can get involved.

**It helps you hire and recruit other developers.**

After salary, two of the top job search considerations for developers are team culture and what they’re building. But, despite that, job listings are typically dry and boring lists of requirements, responsibilities, and expectations. A short team blurb might be included, but it may not even represent the development team fully. Teams can cut through that by giving developers a fuller picture of the team, created by the team.

Inversely, if you’re looking for a job, now you have one place you can go to learn about a team, their culture, what they’re building, and who’s involved. Maybe this information is the motivation you needed to apply or maybe it helps you feel more secure in your possible decision to join the team. Or, maybe it’s the info you need to realize just how miserable you’d be working with that team. Either way, Teams can help you make more informed decisions.

## We Need Your Help

This is the first step, sharing where we’re at. We’ve been thinking about what Teams on Stack Overflow look like, what they can offer, and how they might behave; but now we need your feedback. We’re still in the early stages, but we believe involving the community is vital to strong, successful ideas.

The second step will be a private beta, where the community will <strike>use this in ways that we never dreamed of or intended</strike> test things out and identify where we need to work harder. The private testing timeline is the [obligatory six-to-eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). **A sign-up form will be at the end, so please keep reading.**

## The Proposal (On How Teams Will Work…Initially)

We've got a lot of crazy ideas for these pages, and probably won't have a clue which makes sense until you give us some feedback, but here’s what we think the first version will look like:

**Teams are open-ended…for now.** Meaning we aren't prescribing how they should be used. We reserve the right to change this, but we're interested in seeing what people create teams for and how they organize them.

**Teams are self-forming.** We aren’t going to create them. That’s up to you. They can be of any size…even 1 person.

**Anyone can sign up and join a team.** We’ve considered having a required rep level to create a team, but want anyone to get involved with a team if they want to. So for now, we’re starting without a requirement. If chaos ensues, then we’ll revisit this area...

**Teams are formed around groups of people and the projects they work on.** Most likely this will mean companies (i.e. Stack Overflow, HBO, etc.), sub-teams within companies (i.e. the Trello mobile team, the Microsoft Excel team, etc.), organizations (i.e. Mozilla, W3C, etc.), or open-source projects (i.e. KVM, ASP.NET MVC, etc.).

**Teams can share how they work and what they’ve learned.** What’s your tech stack? What’s the purpose of your team? What projects do you work on that you’re excited about? How can people join your team?

**Joining a team is public.** We are not doing private teams. The goal here is to share information, not hide it behind some secret curtain. When you join a team, you’re added to the team’s roster. Eventually we will also add a list of teams you’re a member of onto your profile, but it won’t be in the beta.

**People can *only* ask questions about the team on the team page.** Wait, does this mean Stack Overflow is a social network? *Emphatically no.* You cannot directly message a particular team member or start random discussion questions. When a new question is created, the team will be notified through their inbox that a new question has come in. If teams receive too many questions, we will explore rolled up notifications or other ideas. Once notified, anyone on the team can answer the question. If the team feels it’s a question that should be on Stack Overflow, they can move that question out into the general questions area.

[image: Questions list proposal]

As far as mechanics are concerned, right now we are thinking that the only things that will be different with team questions are that you will not be able to earn reputation (from asking or answering questions) or offer bounties. Up and downvoting questions/answers, comments, flagging, deleting, and admin functionality will all still apply.

**Team questions will be kept on team pages…for now.** For the time being, we don’t want to clutter the community with questions most people can’t answer.

**This is all great and all, but do you have anything else planned for Teams?**
Well, yes. Yes, we do. It’s still early and everything is subject to change as we move along and hear to your feedback. But we have considered other ideas as well. They are:

- **Projects.** A place where teams can share about projects and the challenges they face(d) while working on them.
- **Team Artifacts.** Blog articles, conference talks, podcast episodes. All the various things that feature your team but that’s strewn across the worldwide interwebs.
- **Team Opportunities.** Have an opening on your team? Want developers to know how to get involved with your open-source project? We’ll provide an area where teams can list job opportunities or sign-up instructions.
- **Following Teams.** Stay up-to-date when teams answer a new question, update or post a new project, post a new job, or anything else that updates their page.
- **Team Rep & Badge Totals.** Show off your team’s brilliance within an aggregated reputation and badge area.
- **Top Questions & Answers.** What are the top questions and answers for the team?
- **Team Timeline.** View a team’s activity within one default view. What questions has the team answered? What questions and answers have team members written within the community? New team members. New projects and project updates. New job opportunities. All of this within one view that you can easily scan and catch up on a team’s activity.

## FAQs

- **Can you earn reputation answering team questions?**

  - No. Much like answering questions on Meta, answering team questions is also a reputation-less activity. Badges could potentially be earned however. More details on this will follow.
- **Will you be able to vote on questions and answers?**

  - For now we will allow normal upvoting and downvoting, but mainly because we want to see how voting differs here versus community questions. If we identify areas which could be tweaked, we will address those then...
- **What if someone asks a coding question on a team page?**

  - There will be an easy way to move it into regular Q&A.
- **Will I be able to send a private message to a team member?**

  - Nope. We still have no intention of becoming a social network.
- **Who can join a team page?**

  - Initially people will be able to join team pages through one of two options:

    - A unique URL link which would grant you access into the team.
    - You will be able to set an email address domain, allowing anyone who has a valid email address to join your team.
  - Looking ahead we also foresee other ways people can join teams:

    - Being invited by other team members.
    - When adding roles, schools, or projects onto your profile, you will be asked if you would like to join the team at that time.
    - When linking a GitHub or open source project to your profile, you’ll be asked to create or join a team page at that time.
- **Who can create a team?**

  - Initially anyone can create a team page. You will be able to create a team from the Teams “Overview” page. Eventually you will also be able to create a team from your user profile page when you add a job role, school, or project.
- **Who can edit the team’s summary information?**

  - Any team member can edit a team’s overview, meta information, team members, and projects. We will maintain a historical record of these changes so they can be rolled back in the event something was changed that shouldn’t have been changed.

## Beta Registration

If you would like to help us test this out, please sign up at the form link below. We will need to know the following things about you:

1. Your Stack Overflow profile URL
2. Your email address
3. Your team name
4. Your team size (team size especially helps us because we will want to see how teams of varying sizes will utilize the team page).

## [Sign-up for the private beta](http://goo.gl/forms/nosBAAcbvG)

Comment: Users can be part of multiple teams, right? Like, a company and an Open Source project?

Comment: You managed to write at least three quarters of this post with breathless "this is revolutionary, this will change Q&A forever" language before actually saying what teams are.  I'm still not entirely clear what they are.  It almost sounds like you just want a new SE site where each tag wiki represents a team rather than a concept.  Why does this require an entirely new application?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yep, you'll be able to be on multiple teams.

Comment: Are you going to try to authenticate teams?  How are you going to prevent a bunch of people from creating "Jon Skeet's team" or "MSDN"?

Comment: what did I just read?

Comment: It's a meta post, @Will.

Comment: *Team Rep & Badge Totals* - Will they still be useless Internet points when they can impact not just a person's but an organization's real world reputation? What happens when people on the same team start up voting each other's posts? Is it not a problem as long as it's not serial voting?

Comment: @AnnaLear while it's on a meta site for programmers, it really reads like it should have been directed at investors.  It reads like a sales pitch.  Compare this to the Documenation post, which comes off sounding a lot more like a proposal directed at programmers.

Comment: What's the motivation for creating a team?  Why would my company/group want a team?  We've already got official websites/blogs, Github/BitBucket issue trackers and wikis, Slack chat, Trello planning, etc.

Comment: So is this gonna be a SO-only thing, or would it be possible to have it on other SE sites if it turns out to be successful? I could envision this being on [codegolf.se] as well; for example, we like making new programming languages/esolangs, frequently collaboratively, and I could see a "[Foo] language Q&A" being a very useful thing to have on the site itself. (This would also make it much easier to separate actual challenges from plain "esolang/golfing Q&A," although now I'm kind of getting into meta.PPCG territory :P)

Comment: I'm a little skeptical. Are you going to have somebody reach out to every person who creates a team to vet them? What keeps me from starting a Microsoft Works team? Can other people join the team? Can they create teams with the same name? Will there be a race for people to register names like "Google"? If Google comes along and wants to start a team, are they going to be able to "steal" the name from whoever has it?

Comment: @Doorknob [read Monica's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307520/426671)

Comment: @meagar We don't have vetting on the table - especially since team names (like users) won't be unique. There could be a user group in many cities with overlapping names, etc. That's not to say we won't be thinking about it - we certainly will be. I have to ask though...why in the world would you create a Microsoft Works team???

Comment: @NickCraver Because maybe I have an agenda that includes publishing false and subtly undermining information about my competitor's product? And you're giving me a platform where I can easily masquerade as the author of that product?

Comment: @meagar do you really need to publish undermining information? I mean it's Microsoft Works... Seriously though: we'll have flagging for this sort of thing in immediately. We know anywhere people can type in a box on the internet, it will be abused.

Comment: So... what problem was this solving again?

Comment: So... is this like a permanent AMA sort of thing? Where an employee (or group of employees) field questions from SO users about how they (technically) run their operations?

Comment: @NickCraver Ugh, fine. Suppose I were an employee of StackExchange (I'm not). Suppose my team had an agenda of poisoning the community against ExpertsExchange (we don't). What stops me from creating a team representing ExpertsExchange and publishing things about how we demand our developers work 12 hour days and take no vacations and are required to wear full suits in the office? One of the things claimed is that this will be the "one place" you need to go to find things out about a team you might work for, before a job interview. It's pretty important that those things be accurate!

Comment: @TravisJ - The problem where people ask questions like, "How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?" (which does happen though they don't always ask about a specific company) or "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?" (though that's more likely to get asked at The Workplace).

Comment: Who doesn't have "poisoning the community against ExpertsExchange" on their agenda?

Comment: @meagar The idea before this goes out to everyone is to have authentication for teams that are also companies.  So if you validate you have an @ expertsexchange email you could become a member.  If not, then you're not on the team.

Comment: @WillCole that doesn't work for a lot of teams. There are open source teams that don't have an `@companyname.com` email address for each employee.

Comment: @meagar Yup, that will only work for companies.  For open source projects we'd still ask for authentication with say github, to check to see if you are a member/contributor to the project.  Still digging in exactly what signals to look for there, but it should cut down on fraudulent pages being created or non-members gaining editing access.

Comment: @BSMP - And of 10 million questions, how many of them have been of that type to make that type of question into a problem which requires this type of solution?

Comment: @TravisJ - No idea. Unless you have a fancy way of searching the data dump I don't know that any regular SO user can tell you what percentage of questions get closed (or just ignored) for being too narrow.

Comment: Not just too narrow, specifically of the type "how does Company X run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?" I think that the number of occurrences must be extremely small. I do not think this is a problem that needs solving.

Comment: This sounds like a combination of LinkedIn and StackOverflow. LinkedIn because it contains the organization that all these members belong to, and StackOverflow for the Q&A portion. I think it's a great idea as it expands on what types of questions can be asked. I've always wanted to ask questions such as "Why did X company do this X way" and with Teams, it's finally possible to see their subjective view on the matter. That said, I feel most for-profit companies would rather NOT use it. I see this being used more for non-profit and open source reasons (IE, a team developing a java package).

Comment: Truth is, we're not gonna know until we try, @Psychrom - that said, if open-source adoption is something that *happens*, I don't think anyone's gonna be sad; we've had multiple requests for something like that in the past, and always felt bad we couldn't do much for 'em.

Comment: Right. I was merely commenting on how many high-stakes corporations and even governments would not want their developers releasing potentially important information about how their programs work to the public, and possibly their competitors. I'm certain some, such as Google, probably won't care, but some such as the NSA or FBI probably will not. :P

Comment: I suppose it _has_ been a while since the last hair-brained scheme was announced. Like, what, a couple of weeks?

Comment: At first I thought SO wanted to introduce guilds (with its own fancy name), but I eventually realized that Teams is intended to be the Geocities of software development. News flash: any "team" on a level where they should be interested in Teams - even a single person - is virtually guaranteed to already have their own website. This new site seems extremely unnecessary.

Comment: @BSMP the issue of team members upvoting each other's answers is easily fixed *by not allowing it*. Then team rep becomes a reflection of how useful their answers are to the world *outside* of the team.

Comment: Tavern discussion on this feature: [starts here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4056387#4056387), [ends here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4056411#4056411).

Comment: @TravisJ Regarding [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment255367_307513), questions like that get asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) all the time. There used to be a dev at GitHub who answered questions about the company all the time there. Point is, *there's an obvious demand/audience* for a venue for these sorts of localized questions...and it looks like SO/SE wants some market share `;)`

Comment: I like GitHub's Organizations... and Stack Overflow wants to implement something way better than it... great!

Comment: I was on the fence about Documentation, but this proposal makes the Documentation proposal look absolutely amazing in comparison. I have my doubts that teams will scale well to the entire StackExchange network (although I could be wrong) and I fear that they will either be a) misused b) abused or c) neglected. Perhaps I'm too skeptical or I lack the vision that the SO team has, but upon reading this proposal, I'm asking myself: "What am I really going to DO with this feature?" I don't think it offers that much.

Comment: How long did it take you to get the stackoverflow Twitter account? That is how long it's going to take Microsoft to get the team Microsoft from me.

Comment: Maybe this is great, but atm it rather sounds like you're trying to add features for the sake of adding features. Maybe SO is feature complete? Leave it be?

Comment: @davidism 3/4 down the post? What are you talking about? They explain what the concept is in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: `This sounds like a combination of LinkedIn and StackOverflow` Eww. Now you managed to make an interesting idea sound gross

Comment: the docs thing, good idea, yeah, I (or my company) have no interest in this....

Comment: Why on earth would companies want to post details about their internal software projects in **public** for? The assumption that they will is so incredibly naive, that I can't even begin to understand how someone would come up with that idea.

Comment: This is cool. Soon *all* well-known tech companies will have such a team page. Fantastic recruiting tool. "What software does Stack Overflow run on?" "How do you manage dependencies at Google?" "How do you deploy continuously at Facebook?".

Comment: *the issue of team members upvoting each other's answers is easily fixed by not allowing it.* @Cupcake - I take no issue with that if that's what they decide to do.

Comment: This sounds worse than the documentation plan to be quite honest. The sentiment that this sounds like StackOverflow + LinkedIn is pretty dead on. How about the main issues of StackOverflow (degrading question quality, losing high-ranking answerers, etc.) be addressed and fixed, first? I feel like SE is trying to duck out of the QA game, to be honest.

Comment: @Qix How is this like LinkedIn? Because you can say you work with a Team?

Comment: It's a place for you to "be a part of something" in a professional context. Isn't that what LinkedIn is?

Comment: @Qix In some ways—yes, though Teams are bigger than just companies. LinkedIn is mainly about you. Your resume. Your network. A rolodex of people at a company. Teams is about people sharing about themselves. What do you build (or what are you working on)? What's the team culture like? What do you love about this team?

Comment: So it's Glassdoor, then.

Comment: @Qix If you hate the idea, just say that.

Comment: I'm pointing out that these ideas the product development team has aren't anything new. There are reasons why documentation hasn't been aggregated like what is described, for many of the points brought up the community. This proposal sounds eerily similar to so many other sites out there. I can't actually imagine a product team within SE actually sitting down and saying "what does the programming community face that is a problem we can solve?", coming out with this. I don't hate the idea, but it's definitely not very strong. There are lots of problems in the dev community that can be addressed

Comment: **Can someone please make a TLDR for this?**

Comment: Unfortunately I knew this was coming one day.  This is a mashup of facebook, glassdoor, linkedin, and insert whatever you want into this.  This is a complete disaster.  Its also another way to insert the crappy careers site into the mix.  Stop with all the integration please...

Comment: I don't need StackOverflow to become another social network. It's fine how it is.

Comment: Agreed. Why not have this as a part of the Careers site? When companies try new things like this, I see it as a sign of failure (somewhere). Docs are enough, but this just seems like a way to possibly generate ad revenue or stuff. Or deter company/product based tags and Qs

Comment: Based on the new tl;dr, why is this a completely new site, rather than a minor expansion on Careers?  Careers already has information about a company, a member roster, and recruitment.  (At least that's what I see when I see careers ads.)  Expand who can make a careers profile, allow adding more information to the team, and add a Q&A.  You can still generate revenue by making ads only show up for "pro" teams.

Comment: @davidism Careers' Company Pages are not managed by teams of developers. It's managed by recruiters and people in marketing teams. How is that information valuable to developers? From the feedback we've gotten in our testing—it's not very useful. What they want to know is the stuff we're looking to add.

Comment: @Hynes yes, that's why I'm saying it's not a huge leap to expand careers to be relevant to developers (wasn't "being more relevant to developers" already the point of Careers?) as well as recruiters.  It seems like most of the pieces are already there.  I'd actually find Careers way more useful if it had more permanent, informational company pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a statement about Careers somewhere to the effect of "We wanted to cut through the tactics of other recruiter sites and make this about the developer."  So saying "Careers is for recruiters" doesn't sound like the message it was originally developed for and should probably be improved there, rather than spending development time on a *completely new site*.

Comment: Again this is competition to glassdoor directly in SO, and I personally hate it.  As @davidism mentioned, put this in careers not SO.

Comment: I'll admit that this idea strikes me completely wrong. Documentation still fits in with what I feel the culture of SO to be, that of creating *information* to make the internet a better place. We're already drowning in social sites and places where we can "connect" with others. SO, and SE in general, are one of the few *user*-driven communities on the internet that's about something concrete: an archive of information and a place to get help. Add this to Careers, where it belongs, not to SO.

Comment: @Hynes: To play devil's advocate, how is this information valuable to developers either beyond idle curiosity (and job seeking, but then, why isn't it a part of Careers)? I thought we were trying to deter companies from redirecting general customer support (stuff beyond specific, within the guidelines technical questions) to Stack Overflow, not encourage them and give them a space?

Comment: sure seems like it's becoming a social network to me. as someone who doesn't care about SO careers at all (people actually use that feature?), this is total cruft. i just want to ask questions and get answers. SO is already great for that.

Comment: You included a Far Side comic here with no obvious attribution, and almost certainly no permission from Gary Larson himself, as he has specifically asked everyone to not post his comics onilne: creators.com/a-note-from-gary-larson.html. I would recommend removing the image.

Comment: This feature **does not advance the mission statement of Stack Exchange.** Please remember why we're here: ["...to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal) Doing things just because we can is actively detrimental to that goal, and will worsen Stack Exchange's long-term success. Either explicitly change the mission statement, or - preferably - _please_ don't do this.

Comment: Can you tag the team you created? This way you will be able to search for teams that have the same tag.

Comment: First documentation and now this. This is *exactly* what it feels like when a new member of the board discovers that saying the words "social network" and "niche community resource" very close together can, on occasion, cause the skies to erupt in squalls of free Fed chaffe. My advice: Be a smart frog, *get out of the pot for a moment*, and ask yourself if the temperature seems to have changed a bit. You've done something very right, and gardened the success well. Don't start cross-planting aggressive species in your garden now.

Comment: Personally I would rather pull my fingernails out than get involved in a lot of fake jollity on a SO team page.  I like my colleagues in real life, but this is a terrible idea.

Comment: @SList Buddy, the SO investors want increased profit year on year! Turning a profit and fulfilling a niche extremely well isn't enough.

Comment: As an extremely small startup of 2 developers (1 being the active coder, aka me), I like the sound of the the Teams ability to try to gain exposure to a project. But it sounds like the intent of teams is to organize public Q&A information with a code/libraries/projects-centricity...how will this not conflict with the Documentation goals? For example, say I (or a larger, more mature open-source project) create a team for my open-source project ibGib....Will my "documentation" Q&A go in Teams or in Documentation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this feature as off-topic because it's not about programming, it's a social network.

Comment: "Documentation is our attempt to help the community address questions which would typically be considered too broad. Teams is our attempt to address items which typically are considered too localized." That's an excellent way of putting it, thanks.

Comment: You better implement this before github gets the idea ;)

Comment: @Boann: It's telling that this post now has 4 *close votes* for off-topic.

Comment: Aaaaand it's closed.

Comment: When I said I'd voted to close the feature I was just emphasizing my feelings on it. I don't think the discussion post should actually be closed.

Comment: Wow. If closing it doesn't show how the community feels about this, I don't know what will.

Comment: @Boann: Obviously a lot of people (me included) agreed with you (though I didn't VTC).

Comment: @Linuxios Votes and responses are a much better way to show how the community feels about this. It only takes 5 people to close a question, but there are ~300 votes on the question already; there's no argument over which measurement has more weight. Especially considering the question is open again already.

Comment: @TylerH: I realize that. I didn't mean it was the right way to respond -- I just meant that it was indicative of how strongly people felt about it to drive them to breach protocol that much.

Comment: I have a better idea: **Stack Overflow MEATS**. We can discuss bacon, beef, small game, sausage, etc.

Comment: @Linuxios Eh, wouldn't be the first time a post like this was closed by users because "it's not a question" or whatever. That's not really how meta works and I wouldn't read much into it.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I know. I do know how I and the other ~120 downvoters feel about this though. Meta is a harsh place :).

Comment: The recent proposals more and more give me the feeling that a company can't drive a community and we need something new. Something free and community driven, not company, growth and project manager driven. If you want to hear my opinion, please fix issues and improve the existing platform, improving means listen to users not to managers. If you want to make this place a hell and destroy everything it ever was, you are on your way.

Comment: Something tells me that this is going to be implemented regardless what anyone says here. "They" are excited about it.

Comment: @zxq9 true dat...I feel SO may be loosing site of what it's community wants in the [quest to actually make a profit.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model/79448#79448)

Comment: Can you post the same question to multiple teams? like "How did you solve X problem?" to teamA, teamB, teamC.

Comment: Team? I love team: https://youtu.be/EoMW8VYb_GE?t=65

Comment: @Liam I'm not just trying to be a sourpuss. SO is acting as though they are running *away* from something fearful instead of *toward* something hopeful. Developer goodwill and 7.9m visits/day is not something to fearful, so perhaps the fear is internal. Rising costs or, more likely, something to do with funding and maybe internal jockeying. These are the wrong reasons to change. Maybe the idea is that with a million well established Google anchors they should exploit the situation because they feel safe. That's what this smells like to me. MySpace tells is a cautionary tale here.

Comment: I voted to close this as I personally find it an annoying feature.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. It totally moves away from the core of what stack overflow is about (specific, objective question+answers), and unnecessarily fragments everything. When would I post a question in the excel team page as opposed to tagging a question with excel? Plus, why would you expect any companies to share details about how they function, scale, or the exact ways they use tools? And how can you honestly say this isn't social networking? Documentation was a great idea. This, not so much.

Comment: Where are you pulling these ideas from? Why not focus on things that you already have that are in dire need of a rewrite/maintenance like the forgotten chat rooms where most users that are sick of answering dupes on main hang out?

Comment: Would it be English only?

Comment: Ok. I'm willing to give it a try. I've contacted my co-workers to see if there is support, and I've filled out the form last week. Now what? When can we start?

Comment: This is an innocent way of having 'stackoverflow superstars'.On the face of it,the idea is plausible and almost brilliant but it ignores one dynamic of the site often overlooked - strangers helping strangers. By having groups with charismatic leaders,its only a matter of time before group members disagree and a lot of things are gonna be said about stackoverflow. Those of us who used to follow the codeigniter story,would identify Fuel framework,Phil Sturgeon et al and we all know what happened to that joint. Think carefully before passing this idea.

Comment: Sometimes team members quit or are fired.  Would a team be able to boot members off in such instances?

Comment: @Cupcake you're a [grammar Nazi](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/307513/5). :P

Comment: not a good idea at all...sorry

Comment: My SO account is hooked up to my FB, which is hooked up to a dead email D:

Comment: I've just signed up with team-name 'google' :p

Comment: @NoAlias yes. If a team member quit or was fired, we would provide a way for that member to be removed. It's still TBD, but we will provide this.

Comment: And I think that you will have, in addition to competitive destruction (read down voting or poisoning) between sith and jedi, you will also have packs of cliquish teams who are infatuated with each other and helically up vote their buds, thereby diminishing the value and validity of positive feedback as well.

Comment: If a team member was found to be bad later, after the posts and up votes, would there be removal of the offending posts, votes, etc.? If I was on Team X, upvoted Y's stuff, then left to work for Z, would I be able to change my mind and remove my votes for Y's stuff now that I'm older, wiser, and and employed by a competing team?

Comment: This comes across rather like Github but for personnel

Comment: From that post I have no idea what a team is, other than it is something to be very excited about. It is also something I never knew I wanted on SO, which I thought was a simple site to get answers to programming questions, and where people voted up good content and voted down bad content. -1

Comment: Wow, impressively disparaging responses. Maybe this should be another stack exchange site, not something hacked onto Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Cupcake So then if I join a strong team I will not be able to vote for the best answer on several questions, how does that make SE better?

Comment: Just to say that a question might not fit in SO in more ways than just too specific or too broad.  This is perhaps obvious, but it is good to have in mind if we consider how SO could cover other kind of questions, though I suspect that there will be strong resistance against any such expansion, no matter which one.  The majority will be afraid that it does not fit in the "core mission" of SO, that such an expansion can be seen as a threat to the current image that SO presents.

Comment: Hmmm, I am on SO every day and I didn't know that teams existed until today.  Anyway, I have always considered the army of SO users across the world my team.  I help them and they help me.

Answer (score 235):

As much as I know folks have been clamoring for this for ages, I gotta say... This scares me a little bit. It may not be a full-on "social network", but it's a big step in that direction - and I'd be shocked if it didn't bring with it some of the known problems endemic to systems that attempt to capture social graphs. We'll learn how to deal with these along the way no doubt...

[image]

### Things to be wary of

- **Interpersonal conflicts**
  Any time there's a self-organized group of people, a pecking order starts to develop - and sometimes all the blood and feathers become too much. This *shouldn't* be too much of a problem for teams that correspond to groups within organizations that already have mechanisms for handling this: HR departments, codes of conduct w/ specific procedures for handling violations, etc. But for those that don't, we'll likely need to develop our own. What happens when someone gets kicked out of a team? What happens when someone is being overbearing in handling team questions? What happens when the SOian People's Front team clashes with the People's Front of SO team?
- **The bad kind of collaboration**
  When folks band together to solve a problem, it is a beautiful thing - a group can accomplish so much more good than any individual. But sometimes folks band together to cause problems... And the same group power applies to that as well.
- **The lights are on but nobody's home**
  Once the novelty wears off, there will be teams that just... leave. Stop answering questions, stop logging in, just disappear without a trace. This is mildly annoying when it's your neighborhood mailing list, but considerably more embarrassing for everyone when it's a big team at a major company that puts the link on their main developer page one day and then disappears into the ether the next. Not that I expect this totally hypothetical scenario to occur *soon*, but we'll want to watch for it.

### Things to be excited about

Like I said, this scares me a bit... But there's much to be hopeful of as well:

- **Product support** [has been a pain-point for quite a while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow). Conveying the message that it's ok to encourage and answer *programming questions* about your product while absolutely essential that you discourage *customer support questions* is hard; actually doing this seems to be even harder. Having a system where you can direct *all* questions about your team's product and then filter them as-needed would be both a boon to organizations already engaged in supporting their work on SO *and* a blessed relief to the good folks who currently have to deal with the mistakes. Quite honestly, I think this is a bigger source of strain than anyone quite realizes - if this plan accomplished *nothing else*, it would be worthwhile for this reason alone.
- **Team building** via Stack Overflow participation is something that's currently neither encouraged nor particularly obvious... Yet when I first signed on, several of my co-workers at the time found the site to be a great way to get to know each other better: sometimes you just don't realize the depth of your peers' knowledge until you get to see them participating in an environment where they're free to ask and answer the questions that truly interest them.
- **Gratuitous stats**
  Oh come on, you *know* someone's gonna put together a "team leaderboard".

Comment: "and then filter them as-needed"... sure, but people will ask at a wrong place. The post addressed moving questions from Team to general Q&A, but who'll get to decide on moving them in the opposite direction?

Comment: I gotta think that'd be a recipe for disaster, @MiceElf: take all the problems we have surrounding migration *now*, and add hundreds/thousands of new destinations... Ever spend an hour in someone's phone system getting transferred between departments? Like that only with more bureaucracy.

Comment: Now that you mention it, product support is a huge win from this proposal and actually seems (to me) to be more compelling than the motivation to allow more localized questions.

Comment: I think Teams may well stand or fall on the product support aspect. If it works then it would appear to be a good way to organise this. The customer support questions stay in the team, but the developer ones get migrated to SO.

Comment: Since you envision Teams as a place for customer support, and there will be a way to move real questions to SO, will there be a way to move support questions to a Team, before it gets downvoted into oblivion and the user loses interest/gets angry?  If we encourage customer support on a Stack Overflow related product, it's guaranteed that many will misinterpret this and make those posts on main.

Comment: If this takes off, there are gonna be waaaaay too many teams for that to be feasible, @davidism - the last thing I wanna see is folks fighting over who gets a question. A better solution will probably be to direct users who aren't already familiar with SO *directly to your team page*, and then just free the programming questions once you've had a chance to review them - that's gonna be a better experience for your users *even when the questions start out on-topic!*

Comment: I was enthusiastic at first about the idea, but thinking a bit more and reading people's feedback, I'm growing less sure whether this is a good direction to take. There seems such a huge possibility that the content created in the Teams section won't be of consistently high quality, and that it will mainly be a huge Quora-like distraction from the core mission; the number of teams that will be able to discuss dev internal stuff, or even expose their employees, in the Teams section may be more limited than we expect; and there is so much left to do on SO proper... but I suppose we shall see

Comment: Maybe only allowing migration to a team page you are part of might be a solution.

Comment: Quora may be a useful contrast here, @Pekka: they took Q&A & made it social; can we take networking and make it open? Remember, SO had a lot of classic problems to work out at first too...

Comment: Maybe, @LisaMM - worth keeping in mind as a possible need at least.

Comment: Are customer support questions in scope? I thought the focus was on how a company creates its product.

Comment: This is all undefined right now, @Gordon. **I** think support questions would be a good use for it, *because that's what I've seen folks trying to use SO for*... But it's really up to you; if you wanna help shape what this becomes, sign up for the beta and mold it to your will...

Comment: Agreed that Product Support is what teams should be used for. The current proposed content, questions about "The Team (Overview, Meta Information), a member roster, projects, community interaction (Questions), and recruitment (Jobs, Get Involved)." is rather lacking in content. But a lot of teams/companies do point their users to SO for support (where the users ask frowned upon questions and get downvoted into oblivion.) Teams seems like a perfect place for companies to be able to direct their users to

Comment: *"can we take networking and make it open?"* You can't, since what you have is a Q&A site. It's decidedly not about networking. You can switch its focus to networking, but then it moves away from Q&A and you lose what makes SO successful.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but this post seems too resigned to this appealingly bad idea.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, @joshua. It could be a bad *system*, but only if we build it blind to potential problems. So, approach with eyes wide open...

Comment: @Shog9 I can agree that having support for individual projects/products on the SE platform could be useful, but this does not appear to address that.

Comment: @Shog9 I do not know what your criteria are for determining the value of an idea, but even the less experienced individuals have pointed out numerous (potential) flaws.  How many potential pitfalls would have to accumulate before the ROI is zero?  Not to mention the fact that no one seems to be able to communicate what the purpose of the feature is.

Answer (score 207):

This sounds like a recipe for worse fragmentation than with Documentation (aka Null Reference), at least as far as the question feature is concerned.

It *might* be a fair assumption that team members will be active and motivated enough to move actual programming questions onto the main site, but if it's not then we are in big trouble. New users will almost certainly think "I have a problem with Excel, I'll post to the Excel team's page!" instead of "This is a programming question, just tag it with Excel." Without very active cleanup, questions/answers will become much harder to find.

Without providing *very* easy and reliable ways of making sure programming questions stay where they belong, I don't see this feature ending very well.

The whole "ask a team a question" thing just feels very social and not very technical anyway. How are we going to deal with the inevitable "What do you think about this?" type questions? Are discussions more permitted (as on Meta)?

Adding to this problem are the "teams of one". Let's say someone like Jon Skeet (important part, well known) decides he wants to answer questions off on his own area (not that Jon Skeet would ever do such a thing) and creates a "solo" team. Questions asked to this person (which is really what it is at this point) aren't going to be community moderated or visible, and if they like answering the programming questions that come their way, the community loses.

I'm not saying these problems cannot be overcome, but suffice it to say I'm skeptical.

Comment: This wast the first thing I thought of as well.  Perhaps there ought to be a way for high-rep users (say, 20k+?) to relocate Team questions back to Q&A?

Comment: I'm not saying you don't have a point (or that the Teams team hasn't already thought about how to tackle this), but here's something to consider: the big "ask question" button at the top of every page in the main site navigation will still be the way most people ask questions and will still go to the main Q&A section of the site. In order to ask a question on a team page, a user will actually have to to *more* work: navigate to the Teams section, then to a specific team, then to the questions section for that team.

Comment: I love the proposal but this is a good point. Can we really enforce a culture where programming questions (which will inevitably show up on team pages) will be moved to the main site with prejudice? (Then again, do we really need to, provided that the answers are decent....?)

Comment: @Laura I can imagine "beginner team" pages popping up, so that new users can ask questions without fearing downvotes.  Despite the extra work, if it benefits them I can imagine them doing it, and they *will* ineveitably get answers.  Which sounds similar to the "Don't make Programmers SO's toilet" event.

Comment: @Laura I'm fairly sure a lot of users will take it upon themselves to do that work, especially if their question gets shot down on the main site initially. It really is something to bear in mind

Comment: @BenCollins The person receiving the question on the team side will be able to do that - they are the better experts for what is/isn't on-topic vs. for the team as it comes in.

Comment: Yeah, @davidism has a point.  What does moderation for this look like?  Could questions go directly to a moderation queue specific to that team rather than appearing immediately?  That may discourage some of the users who might just want to avoid the rep/privileges boundaries.

Comment: @NickCraver What I'm predicting is that people will create teams with the express idea to ignore any idea of "on topic".  In other words, how are the teams moderated, not the posts?

Comment: I think the problem @davidism is even bigger than the one I wrote about. Presumably moderators could find and shut these down, but its even more cause for concern.

Comment: @Laura For users frustrated with the existing experience (or even those who just think that going directly to the "experts" is the best path) I have little doubt they will do so, unless we hide the feature like we do chat

Comment: What @davidism mentions is a real danger, but it could be relatively easily policed by mods. Taking a team page down after receiving a flag is easy, as easy as taking down a wildly off topic chat room, and little harm would be done if such a place lived for a while before being discovered.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Agreed, but who will be raising such flags? I can easily imagine the number of Teams could grow such that just perusing the list for honeypots would become non-trivial.

Comment: @davidism Well, we're interested to see in the beta what types of teams arise.  Our initial thoughts were they'd mostly be open source projects and companies (ie groups of people who build things together they want to show off).  We have no interest in the "People who want to ask inane questions to each other" team because they don't build anything.  We're keeping it open in the beta though to see what gets created and where that moderation will be needed.

Comment: @WillCole yes, I understand what you *want* the feature to be, and I'm sure it will be that way in the *private* beta.  What I'm asking is how we moderate the teams once anyone can use it.

Comment: @davidism I don't see team [creation] moderation as inherently any more problematic than question moderation. In other words, I'm sure team creation rate will be [orders of magnitude] lower than question creation rate. To your point, still, we may need/want to deploy some new moderation mechanism(s) to manage the team creation and flagged teams.

Comment: @TallJeff I’m not sure about that. If teams open up a whole new range of digital achievements (badges, and a new category of reputation), then people will automatically try to game it. And if it’s possible for them to game it without actually contributing to the idea (of creating a real team), then they will still absolutely do it.

Comment: @poke No new categories of reputation will be created for Teams. We're open to considering new badges—but even then, we don't know. Badges are a motivator for more individual activity. Having an area on Stack Overflow to talk about your team already provides a lot more value then an individual achievement. You have a platform to share about your team, the projects you work, what excites your team, who you work with, etc.

Comment: @TallJeff: It is a fixable problem, but davidson is right to be concerned. It's also worth asking -- the rate might be (theoretically) lower, but this would still be adding a whole new burden to a moderation system that's already struggling slightly under scale. The difficulties in making the review system do anything meaningful or helpful to the diamond mods shows that this is in no way a trivial problem. Between this, Documentation, and SO itself, isn't that a bit much to ask of the diamond mods?

Comment: This is my biggest confusion as well. Where do you draw the line between this is a question for SO that involves product X and this is a question for product X's team?

Comment: This is an attempt by Stack Exchange to make some money off of the great job they have been doing helping programmers. To be more specific, it's another iteration of Stack Overflow Carriers. Unfortunately, I think it's an ill-advized way to go about it. At best, it will be as moribund as  Carriers. At worst, it will introduce more clutter, fragmentation and rancor into Stack Overflow world.

Answer (score 142):

> Wait, does this mean Stack Overflow a social network? *Emphatically no.*

Hm... a lot of the future plans sound very much like a social network to me:

- "Teams are an extension of your profile..."
- "Team Artifacts" (yet another place to click "share now"?)
- "Following Teams"
- "Team Timeline"

Even the sign-up options have that "viral! join the herd now!" aspect:

- "When adding roles, schools, or projects onto your profile, you will be asked if you would like to join the team at that time."
- "When linking a Github or open source project to your profile, you’ll be asked to create or join a team page at that time."

The only thing you explicitly rule out is sending a private message; if Twitter removed Direct Messages tomorrow, would it cease to be a Social Network?

Sure, it will be a Stack Overflow flavoured social network, but it feels a lot more like a replacement for an organisation's Facebook or Google+ page than it does a community resource.

To be constructive, I think the key problem is giving the functionality a *technical focus* - less of the "why we're so great and you should come to us not those other schmucks", and more of the "here's the widget we use to floob our blombles". But quite what blombles need floobing that other sites don't already offer widgets for, I'm not sure...

Comment: To address your specific points up top: is your resume considered social? Teams are meant to be about things you make or do, along the same lines. Team Artifacts would literally be things you build - I'm not sure how "share now" is yielded from that, but let us know and we'll clarify. Following teams, at this point, only has if they have opening later - we're working on this but they're definitely not social features of any sort. The timeline would be activity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This. @NickCraver When I read the title of this post my first thought was "Oh no, we are going into social network hell" and then I read it, and it *still* sounds like a social network (albeit with a technical focus). One of the most powerful things about SO is that we are all here crowdsourcing information. This just seems like a massive distraction whose sole function is to take that crowd and segment it into their own little worlds (but thats just my opinion of course :) )

Comment: @NickCraver Maybe the wording of the summary is way off then, because this just sounds like what you'd post to Facebook/Google+/Pinterest/whatever to me: "Blog articles, conference talks, podcast episodes. All the various things that features your team but that’s strewn across the worldwide interwebs." Nobody is going to post critiques of themselves, they're going to use this as a shop window - Post Here, Follow This, Catch Up Here.

Comment: As for a resume being social, go ask LinkedIn...

Comment: @IMSoP valid points on the reading. As for LinkedIn - the resume piece isn't social. They bolted on many things (that aren't a resume) to make something social. FWIW, I don't have a LinkedIn account, because of what they turned into.

Comment: @NickCraver Without the "things bolted on", maybe a resume isn't social; but it's not a very interesting premise for a website, either, because I can host it on my own website, or a million existing sites which have the "things bolted on" which I want to use. What, then, is the motivation for people to post information to their Team page, if it's not for people to interact with it, socially?

Comment: @Nick `I don't have a LinkedIn account, because of what they turned into` good man.

Comment: Team pages are for people to interact - but it'd be firmly on programming and related topics. You wouldn't be able to post cat pictures, photograph your breakfast, or hit on that cute guy/girl. `they're going to use this as a shop window` sure, and that's fine as long as it's open, free - and programming related.

Comment: @Pekka웃 OK, so it's a specialised social network firmly focussed on programming and related topics, just as LinkedIn is a social network focussed on professional networking, and Instagram is a social network focussed on photos. I don't think that's automatically a Bad Thing, but let's call a spade a spade. It's both more and less than a Q&A site; it's (presumably) not a Project Management tool; it's a site where individuals outside of a Team can connect, in a variety of formats, with individuals inside a Team - it's social networking, Stack Overflow style!

Comment: Waiting to hear back on @IMSoP response..that was very valid...cricket cricket...

Comment: @Pekka웃 Also, "You wouldn't be able to post cat pictures, photograph your breakfast" - who is going to stop you? What motivation will the community have to mark Stack Overflow's latest unicorn video as Off Topic from their own Team page? Or if the community does get strict, what motivation will there be for Teams to learn the rules, rather than just using a different service to provide their shop window?

Comment: Plus the idea davidism mentioned on another answer. What about teams with just one single member? Why is this not 'interacting with a single person' and therefore smells like the 'social reference' where the whole topic is 'emphatically' against?

Comment: @bully well, I was actually thinking of "teams" that weren't real, just a place to post questions that couldn't get downvoted.  I wasn't referring to how many people would "belong" to that team or whether it was social.  But I could see it going that way too.

Answer (score 135):

Disclaimer: I'm 15, I don't have a job, and I still do homework. So, what services of Stack Overflow are available to me? Just the site. And maybe Meta. SO Careers is basically useless for me, since I'm not looking for a job, and I don't care. I'm putting this out in the open just in case it affects my answer.

---

I've got a little Open Source company of my own. It's called Arctic Lights. I haven't really put anything up yet, since I'm still developing it, but right now, my main focus is on the creation of an API (called Tundra) and sort of booklet to assist people who are learning to program.

So here I have, my own little company called Arctic Lights. I create a "team" for use on this page. What do I do?

From these "example" questions on the picture, what kind of questions am I to expect? I can only expect questions, that would just be things that would be listed in my repository wiki. Things such as:

- How do I contribute?
- Why do you host this on GitHub? Why not BitBucket?
- FOOLS! YOU GUYS DECLINED MY PULL REQUEST??? HOW DARE YOU?

There is something about all this: these are all common questions that are likely to be asked on a project, or even organization's website. I already have a platform for this: Github has things like GitHub Pages, and I can even run websites for free on places like Wix.

*So how is this useful for me*? I don't know. It doesn't seem useful for me at all. It simply duplicates what I've got, my policies and questions, and it just wastes my time: another thing to see which I've answered before.

---

In my eyes, this is a way to create a customer support platform *for companies*. I'm not sure how that would even fit in: most companies have their own platforms anyway. These questions won't be useful to anyone but those involved in companies. Questions would simply arise from the mere curiosity of people themselves.

---

It's quite likely that I don't understand what's happening here, and don't fully get the benefits and implications that this would bring. In essence, it feels like it solves a problem — product support — but creates more at the same time.

---

I keep thinking about this more and more, and have thought of more potential issues:

- Docs were great. They solved a recurrent problem: the lack of documentation. What problem does this solve?
- Teams is the same thing as [Artificial Intelligence](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/). Questions will simply be asked by the merely curious.

  > I committed to this proposal some time ago, hoping that this might become a site for researchers or knowledgeable academics asking serious technical questions about artificial intelligence here. It seems I was dearly mistaken ... Most of the questions are those asked by the merely curious.

Comment: I don't think you're really missing anything. I agree 100%.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me saying, that is a very mature post from one so young.

Comment: The "Things such as..." list is missing some potentially useful questions (which I believe were highlighted in the original post as well). Like "I see you mix $library1 and $library2 to complete $task, can you explain why not just use one since they both do the same $list of things?" or "Can you share your experience with $new_and_shiny_app as early adopters?" etc.

Comment: "n my eyes, this is a way to create a customer support platform for companies. I'm not sure how that would even fit in: most companies have there own platforms anyway. These questions won't be useful to anyone but those involved in companies. Questions would simply arise from the mere curiosity of people themselves." A lot of companies that cater to developers push them to post on SO - this could be a great developer community tool for companies.

Comment: Forget all the other fluff in the post - I'm onboard a centralized place for a company to help answer developers questions around developers consuming their api's / products. THAT would make my life easier as an engineer.

Comment: I am over twice your age, but I also have a very small open-source startup. The difference between SO(I think) and GitHub wiki would be at least twofold: 1: question driven documentation, which puts the emphasis on the yagni aspect of documentation, and 2) Gamefied up/down voting for moderation for convenience. These two aspects I think combined with the traffic SO has gotten over the years (bc of their quality of implementation) is the reason why SO is the best source for online programming questions. Thats how I see it anyway.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's pretty good for a 15yo person, you'll be a millionaire before you are 23

Comment: @red2nb If you like ziz's style, come on over to opensource.stackexchange.com where Ziz is one of our mods. :) End of blatant advertising

Comment: @kdopen Ha! That's priceless. :D

Comment: @AwalGarg But again, you're proving my second issue: that these questions will be asked by the merely curious. Those sorts of questions aren't going to be solving specific problems that affect people. To be honest, I don't see the questions that you mention as being useful.

Comment: Awesome post for a 15 year old. Can I be on your team?

Comment: @Prescott I agree with your second comment. I see a lot of small-medium communities/companies/"teams" using SO for product support. Currently, they just use tags. Any questions related to that comm/comp/team could only be found through a brittle search. This would give them a stronger platform to host questions about using their product.

Comment: @Zizouz212 well those "merely curious" people are quite a lot in number. If [so] wants to cater to them, I don't see the harm ;)

Answer (score 93):

What problem is this trying to solve?

I'm probably biased as one of the top users and a moderator on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour). We handle questions about this ALL THE TIME. Some of my thoughts...

> > It helps you hire and recruit other developers.
>
> After salary, two of the top job search considerations for developers are team culture and what they’re building. But, despite that, job listings are typically dry and boring lists of requirements, responsibilities, and expectations. A short team blurb might be included, but it may not even represent the development team fully. Teams can cut through that by giving developers a fuller picture of the team, created by the team.
>
> Inversely, if you’re looking for a job, now you have one place you can go to learn about a team, their culture, what they’re building, and who’s involved. Maybe this information is the motivation you needed to apply or maybe it helps you feel more secure in your possible decision to join the team. Or, maybe it’s the info you need to realize just how miserable you’d be working with that team. Either way, Teams can help you make more informed decisions.

If I'm looking for a company, I'm not going to really believe a bunch of <s>marketing material</s> content posted online in what will basically be marketing.

I'm going to believe things said by those <s>companies</s> users.

OK, great, so a team is composed of real people. Is this valuable still?

How many companies are going to actively allow their employees to post, ah, less than positive content about them? Let alone inside business information? This is some of the main stuff that matters - the problem areas. A non-anonymous thing is going to make it really, *really* hard to get specific feedback. Even if it is entirely anonymous I'm still not convinced it'd be successful.

And on the flipside, would employees want to contribute meaningful content? Many companies have really strict social media standards. We on The Workplace get all sorts of questions about people who make single tweets, Facebook posts, etc. and run into problems.

All this might not be the case in startup cultures, where I suspect general tolerance for sharing practices/social media content is much more accepted. But many people don't work in those company cultures.

---

However I still think this is a great idea. The focus on the career/workplace related aspect? Meh.

But the ability to basically have mini-Stack Overflow sites means that the [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History) process can now be bypassed for one-off projects. If I and a few other people create an application, we can have our customer support basically work as part of Stack Overflow. This is great.

I see a lot of potential for this to be quite useful for these sorts of purposes.

Comment: Agreed on the company part. I would really like to create and help manage a team for the company I currently work for. It would probably help their exposure and make them possibly more attractive to work for. But at this point, I can already see that this will probably require a lot organization and management interaction. The company already has a very flexible culture, but that doesn’t mean that everybody can just do and write what they want. I can totally see this work for public and open companies like Stack Overflow; but for other companies, e.g. those that work in B2B? Not really.

Comment: I agree regarding the business inside information.  If we're doing something really cool, then we're not going to want to talk about it publicly because (a) it might not be "ready" for public view -- a crappy demonstration of a great product can kill it (b) other smart teams may pick up on what we're doing and beat us to it.

Comment: I think the problem this solves is 'We created a great useful, website. How can we monetize it?'

Answer (score 82):

> If the team feels it’s a question that should be on Stack Overflow, they can move that question out into the general questions area.

How will this work with questions that are clearly out of Stack Overflow's scope? Will there be other "migration paths" (for want of a better term) to Server Fault, Programmers or The Workplace? Will we be able to reject these migrations if we feel that the question is still too opinion based/broad/what ever?

I'm concerned because none of your example questions that you expect to be asked in the Teams area are remotely on topic for Stack Overflow or indeed any of the sites I've mentioned.

Comment: We haven't thought about migration paths - that's a good point to consider. For team questions they don't *need* to be in scope on SO, just for the team. If a question is neither and trash...we have a nice round bin in the corner it'll likely end up in. To be clear: team questions will not appear in Stack Overflow proper. Only if they *are* on-topic and a team member says so when they are received and answered are they converted into normal Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @NickCraver - I understood that bit ;) It was just that all the example questions would be definitely off topic on SO, and probably off topic elsewhere too.

Comment: I like the idea of being able to send team questions to other sites. I'd like it a lot *more* if you had to have a "team presence" of some sort on the destination site in order to send it there... Imagine Google's cloud team on  both SO and SF, answering support questions internally and sending those that were suited to the appropriate site to be answered.

Comment: @Shog9 - Has anyone even reached out to determine if that imagination is actually a possibility? I feel like there would be more support for this feature if there was more support from actual teams. At the moment it kind of feels like "Field of Dreams".

Answer (score 76):

Could question visibility be the idea's Achilles' heel?

How is the community going to monitor, and vote on, incoming team questions? Crowdsourced moderation is why SO is what it is, after all. The community will kill spam within a minute or two, low quality stuff gets downvoted quickly.

How will you achieve that for team questions? How will you prevent, for example, badly maintained team pages from becoming ghost towns with low quality questions and outright spam?

You can't count entirely on team page members to keep the place clean, and you can't exactly show team questions on SO's front page.

Will moderators do the rest of the cleanup? Can they? If not, who else can - the community through a review queue? Would that work?

Or is all this overestimating the amount of content that would be coming in?

Comment: We were mostly concerned with not distracting from core Q&A with new team Q&A. If we need more visibility into the team questions it should be pretty straightforward to provide lists of all team questions.

Comment: We've also thought about exposing team questions on the /teams view, and a review queue for them if flagged, etc. All of the current moderation routes are currently on the table - and we certainly don't want to overload moderators.

Comment: You could provide lists of team questions, but would anyone want to go through them on a regular basis? Hardly. It's different from browsing questions in tags you know that you might want to answer. It would probably boil down to some form of moderation queue. (Just playing devil's advocate here - I don't think in the slightest that this will kill the idea, it's just a big snag)

Comment: I think if the questions are targeted at a group of people, it is up to those people whether the question should be closed or not (to some degree)

Comment: @TinyGiant Along the lines of your thought, it's quite possible the team should have much more autonomy over team questions. For example, maybe team questions would end up only appearing to the poster and the team members until the question is answered by the team. The team can close them, etc.

Comment: @TallJeff The only thing with that is that a team can then just close any questions they don't want to answer and there wouldn't be any record of the question being asked. Whether that is a problem or not.... we'll see I guess.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Team pages are more than just questions though. The fact that you can ask a team a question means they put in a certain amount of effort to create the page in the first place. There will be other content there as well. If pages start becoming ghost towns, then we can address that then. That becomes our problem of finding ways to engage people more. That's not a community mod problem.

Answer (score 75):

Is Stack Overflow expanding too fast? Stack Overflow introduces Documentation and Teams in a short time frame. We don't even know how Documentation will be received nor whether the concept holds.

From millions of visitors, how many users are really active? Can they be active on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Documentation and Teams at the same time? Especially in the beginning I expect Documentation to require much work. On the other hand side, the new concepts might motivate new users to become more active.

Personally, I would have delayed Teams until Documentation had reached a "stable" state with decent content and decreasing demand on new topics.

Comment: See, this is the sort of question you could've asked on Stack Overflow's team page if that existed...

Comment: (of course, the answer is "no one knows. We can either sit on our hands, or try stuff & hope for the best - and my fingers are already sore.")

Comment: Any number of people will do any amount of work for imaginary Internet points. We already know this.

Comment: We don't even know if how Documents will be received... true, but does it matter? They are different, unrelated concepts.

Comment: "this is the sort of question you could've asked on Stack Overflow's team page" "of course, the answer is \"no one knows\....". IIUC, questions to which the answer is _obviously_ of the form "no one knows" or "<insert ambiguous answer here>" are _not_ welcome to the [se] QA model. Is the aim to now allow such questions, @Shog9?

Comment: @AwalGarg I imagine the answer would be expanded beyond "no one knows."… at least for us it would be.

Comment: Documentation has a long(er) road ahead of it. Teams is something we feel fairly confident about and we think we could get into Stack Overflow much quicker. Also while we have tens of millions of visitors, we don't have that many people involved. We think there's definitely more room for people to get more involved.

Comment: The aim is to allow folks to answer them in a context where they *won't* be noisy, @awal... Or not answer at all, if the question is not useful. If you emailed us that question right now, we'd answer it privately and no one else would ever benefit from knowing we'd even thought about it - what a loss!

Comment: i think the answer is right on topic in meta. My take of the answer is that the new feature is distracting without clear advantage.

Answer (score 71):

### I think these are all good ideas, except team Q&A

It **may** work for things like Open Source teams, but for anything even vaguely corporate, I foresee team questions falling into the following categories:

- **Technical questions about [company]'s processes: Almost certainly confidential**

  Q: "Team Google Servers, what was your hardware budget for the recent server move?"

  A: "Um, I'm pretty sure that's information we're not allowed to give out on the internet"

  Q: "Oh, how about your hardware setup?"

  A: "Again, pretty sure that's confidential"

  Q: What tools do you use to solve [company-specific] problem

  A: "Confidential"
- **Non-Technical questions about [company]: what would a team be allowed, able and willing to tell you that the company website couldn't?**

  Q: "What's it like to work at [Company]

  A: "It's awesome, you should totally come work for us" - regardless of what they actually think, what employee is going to say "It's terrible". That's an easy way to get fired.
- **Questions that should be on other sites:**

  Q: "How do you make remote working work across multiple timezones?"

  A: "Blatantly a workplace.SE question [migrate]"

  Q: "What tools do you use to solve [generic] problem:"

  A: "That should be asked on SO [migrate]"

  Q: "[Company Application/Library/whatever] Isn't working, please help!"

  A: "Again, either entirely Off-Topic, or SO [Migrate]"

And even if they aren't **every** question, I think that covers the vast majority. What team is going to want to spend 95% of their time deleting, migrating, downvoting and otherwise dealing with Off-Topic questions?

Comment: Hadn't considered the confidential nature of questions, maybe this becomes something much more useful for open source teams?

Comment: Good point, added that in.

Comment: @Zak — you could be right. Maybe team questions _doesn't_ work and what happens is what you laid out; but maybe you're wrong as well. Even if I grant you Google won't answer these questions, I know Stack Overflow would. And again—maybe we're unique here—but we don't think we are. For every Google out there, you have a number of smaller teams who might be more than willing to share the general parameters at least and specifics at best.

Comment: I disagree, @Zak - team q&a is what makes this *interesting!* Anyone can set up a vanity page for their team with minimal effort today; heck, they can link to it from their SO profile if they wish. Integrating that offers some minor convenience, but its hardly compelling - but q&a is hard to do well, as many have found to their dismay. If we can help with that, we'll be offering folks something with real value - yes, there'll be challenges, but they'll be worth the work it takes to overcome them.

Comment: @Shog9, Hynes: But how does this actually help any developers beyond some idle curiosity? Even if (somehow) this is actually valuable to the initial poster, this seems *very* far from the goal of making the internet a better place. Great that you'd make Q&A for teams easier, whatever that means, but I'm still not seeing the value in that.

Comment: Folks seem to be fixated on the "AMA" stuff, but I see that as a sideshow. Look at what folks ask *us:* questions about using the product, fixing their accounts, etc. - you know, stuff they actually need to know. And then, once in a great while, some AMA-style fluff. The meat & potatoes are boring, but they're very important...

Comment: @Shog9: But why should SO provide a platform for other companies to do, in essence, customer support?

Comment: Because folks have been asking for it since... Forever? Because folks try to do it *anyway,* and it causes unnecessary stress and work for folks on Stack Overflow? Because we believe that devs communicating with their users is a good thing and should be encouraged?

Comment: @Shog9: I'm skeptical that this will actually reduce the workload for moderation on Stack Overflow, but at least that's better justification than anything given in the original post.

Comment: My creed is basically, "this could yet be a complete disaster"... But that's no reason not to try new things!

Comment: @Shog9: OK. I can accept that. :).

Comment: I had the same thought about the server budget example. It seems like the most active questioners would be people trying to sell me stuff or competitors.

Answer (score 35):

I'm dubious whether "it has to be about the team" isn't too broad a requirement for incoming questions (as much as "has to be on topic for SO" is too narrow.)

What about the inevitable "How much money do you make, John Carmack?", "What is the status of the Oculus Rift and why did you sell out, Palmer Luckey?", "Can you fix this code for me, Nick Craver" et al.?

The last example is going to be easy to squelch, but where do you draw the line on legitimate questions for teams that have nothing, or very little, to do with programming at all? Are questions about programmer chairs and tables (and programming on a boat) on topic? What would be the rules governing this?

And even when there is a set of rules - different teams will have differing ideas of what is on-topic for them and what they are willing to respond to. Who gets the final say on this? SO/the community/moderators, or the teams themselves? If it's not the teams themselves, is this not going to create strife?

But perhaps that's something that will sort itself out during the Beta.

Comment: Internally, we haven't fully figured out the Q&A portion of the team page. A hypothesis I have currently is that it might be good if teams can toggle the Q&A mode: off, on, on but team asked (the questions are asked and answered by team members in a FAQ-like manner). That's my conclusion upon reading some of the initial reactions here. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, we'll definitely have to work out what kind of Q&A is allowed. It won't be a section to ask anything at all -- it should still be focused on sharing interesting knowledge, not just pestering people.

Comment: @Haney that would give the team some control, sounds good. Would also probably help prevent some of the ghost towns resulting from questions amassing on an inactive team page.

Comment: To add to @Haney, we might also disable Q&A automatically if a team hasn't answered in some time period - that would prevent it being used as a spam box/ghost town, etc. We'll watch feedback here for a while and see what other ideas are proposed as well - we're not dead set on any approach.

Comment: That sounds pretty effective for protecting the teams. Another thing though, what happens if a team's ideas about what is on topic differ from the community's? Suppose a game dev team allows wildly off topic questions on how they 3D scanned their characters from actors and what problems they ran into, and members of the community vote to close them based on whatever set of rules is in force by then. The team gets angry because their interactions are shut down. What happens, and who decides?

Comment: @Pekka웃 those kinds of things are exactly what the beta will hopefully shake out. I don't know the answer, but I am confident that we'll figure it out.

Comment: I often wondered about using a GeekDesk on a boat... how is this *not* StackOverflow turning into a discussion forum?  Don't we already have chatrooms for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 34):

I like this idea.

But I'm not too sure how it'll be used.

I'm thinking of my own use case, of course: Working at a Startup that [tries to build software in the open](https://medium.com/@gortok/open-sourcing-jewelbots-1061c1f9f8f5) and indeed, our reason for existing is to introduce others to programming and technology; so even if I can't find an immediate use for Teams, it feels like it should fit.

But what would I use it for?  It seems like it could end up being a "Quora For Development Teams", but Stack Overflow's strength has always been the conveying of technical information.  So while it's cool that we have the option to talk about the technical considerations teams take on, I fear it'll turn into [Why didn't Twitter's Performance problems doom it early on?](https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Twitters-performance-problems-doom-it-early-on)

I like the substance; but really don't want the rubber-necking and navel-gazing that permeates the internet.

Stack Overflow has always shy'd away from Bikeshedding, and I'm afraid that "Teams" will focus on just that.

Comment: This article certainly seems to be missing a problem statement - it gives the impression (which I'm sure is wrong!) of a conversation in the SO office along the lines of "We should build something for teams!" "Like what?" "I don't know, let's build a beta of some stuff and see what happens"

Comment: @IMSoP isn't that how Stack Overflow started?

Comment: @Jin I got the impression that Stack Overflow started with a perceived need / gap in the market, not with Joel and Jeff brainstorming interesting projects they could set up. They didn't know exactly what it was going to look like, but they had some idea of what they wanted to achieve. The way this has been pitched seems to be lacking that focus - it's like someone wrote the heading "Stack Overflow Teams" on the whiteboard and everyone brainstormed from there. Again, I'm guessing this is just the way it's been communicated, and internally there's a lot more idea of what the aims are and aren't.

Comment: @IMSoP, precisely, original SO was iterating towards solving a real problem. This is just an idea iterating to discover what problems it might solve.

Comment: @Benjol: AKA, the bad startup model.

Answer (score 29):

The title of this question made me think of "expert teams", so users who group themselves under a tag, for better coordination. Like a group of [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) experts, who know of good canonical questions in their tags, who can cleanup commonly asked questions by closing them as duplicates and who can work together find and answer the harder, more interesting questions. Or maybe they can guide users in asking good questions in their tags.

But no.

I'm sorry, but all examples in the OP are too localized. It's very nice that company X spent Y amount of money on Z servers, but that does in no way guarantee that the same approach will work for a random user's question that more or less touches the same subject.

I can see this becoming a "blog post request" feature, where a user "lazily" asks  a company *"How do you do X?"*, where that company now is going to spend time and effort to answer that very specific, localized question that may or may not help others.

To make this more constructive than a rant:

- For whom are these questions supposed to be interesting?
- For whom are these answers supposed to be interesting?
- How are "personal advice requests" going to be prevented, if you want that?
- Exactly what kind of questions and answers are you looking for? Do you have examples?
- Have you done a test-flight with some teams and what was the outcome?

Comment: "Have you done a test-flight with some teams and what was the outcome?" That's why we made this post. So people could [sign-up for the test flight and we see the outcome is.](http://goo.gl/forms/nosBAAcbvG) Please participate and help us test this out. :)

Comment: @Hynes I would love to, but I'm currently not in a team, nor do I have contact with other SO members. I wouldn't know how to coordinate the forming of a team. :)

Comment: Arranging teams of experts around one particular SO tag actually sounds like a much better idea! To improve FAQs and canonical duplicates, to make sure the Wiki is relevant and correct etc. Perhaps for each major tag, enable an "expert" tag which you will only be able to add to your questions once you reach a certain reputation in the "base" tag (for example silver badge). This might motivate the technical experts to stay on SO and not abandon the site - unless people haven't noticed the experts are currently fleeing from SO because of the crap flood.

Comment: @Lundin except we already do this with Chat, for example the Python room regularly discusses canonical questions, works to clean up the tag, and is a place to ask more general questions.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as you and was very excited about the idea of being able to create my C# Gang of 4 Team,  having its own reputation points. For me this would have been a killer. I'm the kind of SO user who don't care about its reputation points, but I'd care much more for my points, and find them more legitimate if they were at an expert team level. I think if they had been faithful to their brand, it is the direction they would have taken. Today they are trying to change their brand and create a social network to make more profits.

Comment: @davidism Far from every programming language got active chats on SO, and then there's also the tags that are used even less frequently.

Comment: @Lundin so if users of those languages can't organize around a chat room, what makes you think they'll organize around a team page any better?

Comment: @davidism A chat requires that you are constantly available, and it is a pretty bad medium for anything formal. There's no logs and if they are, they are filled with "noise". And there's actually no guarantees that the people present in the chat have the necessary knowledge or rep to make such changes to the site. But indeed, I don't think many SO users will organize around a team page, no matter the purpose.

Comment: @Lundin You seem to have literally no idea how SO chats work. They are completely asynchronous and have a permanent public log. So no, there’s no need at all to be constantly available. And if you get people together to discuss a certain topic, you can also easily avoid noise. The rest of your comment also applies to theoretical teams.

Comment: @poke I do know how they work, do you? If 10+ people are chatting away in it about random topics, good luck tracking anything meaningful in the log through all those noise comments.

Comment: @Lundin not sure what else I can say on this that I and poke haven't already.  My experience in the Python room over the last two years is nothing like what you describe.  It's perfectly possible to maintain order.

Answer (score 24):

I'm afraid my cynical half sees this as *"Stack Overflow is pretty much done, what can we do now to justify having all these leet developers?"*.

Here are the uses cases that I've managed to pull out of the pile:

1. shopfront for attracting new hires
2. answering too-localized technical questions about team product
3. providing support for team products

Beyond the fact that these use cases seem to be mentioned in different places by different members of the team, I see the following problems:

1. If this is an official representation of the company, rather than getting developers more involved in Careers, this is going to get HR more involved in SO. Yoopie.
2. This is more interesting, but we've spent the last 4-or-more years being beaten around the head because 'interesting' is not a valid motivation for asking/answering questions.
3. Facebook.SO

Comment: I know Facebook.SO poisoned the well here (and for a whole bunch of related ideas), but please do consider that the problem there may have been primarily... Facebook. If we'd offered that feature to Mozilla or something, we might all have a rather different view on the subject now - not that we should ignore the potential problem, but neither should we ignore the potential advantages when it comes to groups that *do* care about developers.

Comment: @Shog9, the big problem to me is around official/non-official representation of the company. If it were clearly one or the other, that would at least be easier to reason about. Fuzzy is where the problems happen, and I think that it's this that you/we should be concentrating on, not the technical wow factor.

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps they could be improved, but your example questions do not seem to necessitate anything other than a new Stack Exchange site based on practices applied by specific companies and organizations.

Additionally, this idea seems biased toward open projects that wouldn't mind sharing these metrics. I'm not sure I can say the same for companies like Oracle and Microsoft. I can say that the company that I work for would not allow this without getting some prior approval to share operating information, and even then, I'm not sure I would want to ask.

> - "How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?",
> - "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?", or
> - "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?"

I suggest instead you create a Stack Exchange site organized around sharing industry best practices that are not specifically related to code (where industry/company is a `tag`, not a `team`).

This would be a good place to share Q&A about processes and methodologies. For example, questions I am curious about in general:

- Agile

  1. How long are your sprints? Does it vary between projects?
  2. What technique do you use for story pointing?
  3. To what extent are your actual users involved in writing user stories?
- Development process

  1. Do you practice [pair programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming)? How often? In what situations?
  2. Do you have dedicated QA resources?
  3. What percentage of code gets reviewed? What is the coverage like? Is it a formalized process, explain?
- Documentation

  1. Do you generate documentation or create by hand? What tools do you use?
  2. Who writes the documentation; developers? Dedicated writers?
  3. How do you handle branding of different products within the same company? How about across the parent company (for companies with many business units)?

Comment: Having a “one question, multiple companies answer” site rather than a bunch of “one question, one company answers” subsites definitely sounds like a better idea. Right now, it seems like this will only lead to a huge question fragmentation with no way to actually objectively compare answers.

Comment: The proposed new site *would* need a way to verify that answerers had the credentials to answer authoritatively. On the upside, if SE built such a system, they could then use it for themselves on every meta to allow all employees to make official posts when necessary without needing a diamond.

Comment: If there are concerns already about getting enough traffic to these team areas (and questions) on _Stack Overflow_, I'm not sure how creating new SE sites will solve this. The fact is for the majority of our users: if it's not on Stack Overflow—it doesn't exist. And while maybe Oracle and Microsoft may not share, there are thousands of smaller companies and teams out there who would be.

Comment: There’s a difference between hundreds of separate team areas (a separate question pool for each team) and a single site that has them all in one place though. And there’s no reason why such a single “combined teams site” couldn’t be integrated into SO just like the plan is now.

Comment: Maybe a 'verified content expert' status could be assigned to users after passing some manual verification step, whether it be for a company, the author of a tool, etc. But who to use as the 3rd party certification source? Those users would likely need to expose more public information than usual as part of being verified.

Comment: I've thought about this problem for a while and it's not so easy to get around the problem of companies not willing to share information about their operations. One possibility that I thought about was to allow anonymous responses. I understand this is a potential pandora's box, but as it stands, may be 10% of companies will allow their workers to share sensitive information, but many more would be willing to do so anonymously (probably closer to 90%). If there was a way to monitor anonymous responses, may be moderate them, or restrict their content in some way, it may work out very well.

Comment: @MorDeror: But isn't that a legal gray(ish) area when someone shares something that is under NDA? I can't imagine any company letting their team page stay up much longer after someone divulges a trade secret or information enabling a hack.

Comment: @lunixios - this can become a problem for some narrow scope problems. Let's say you're working on software to control fuel supply in a rocket engine, and there are only two companies out there that deal with it. Then, of course, sharing information would violate the NDA. But if you're implementing a web farm, and you don't disclose any identifying information. What's the harm in sharing how you set up the data caching layer?

Comment: @MorDeror: I'm not saying that there's necessarily harm -- but that doesn't mean that a company lets people share any of the information anyway.

Answer (score 23):

As others, I have difficulties trying to think of actual use cases for this that makes such a project worthwhile. I can think of only two:

1. Open source project teams that answer questions about e.g. design decisions or implementation details that help understanding the project.
2. Open companies that use this to show off their projects and teams and as such increase their exposure for hiring purposes.

The first use case is actually a pretty good one; I can see this being the *real value* for the community. If open source project teams would participate, users could use this to really dig into the codebase, to understand what the developers were thinking. Think about the jQuery team joining, making it possible to ask questions like *“why does function X take the arguments in order Y instead of the more sensible Z?”*, *“why did you decide to combine multiple functionalities into a single function X when you could have split it up for a clearer API?”*, or *“why do you have code X in function Y, is this required for browser Z?”.

These are questions that would really encourage engagement and would help understanding those teams, eventually even allowing those teams to get other people on board after they understood their thinking process. Granted, a lot teams already have other platforms for this, e.g. GitHub issues (although those have a certain threshold of being *issues* so implementation questions are not really encouraged there), or public chat rooms (e.g. Slack). But having a platform which many developers already participate on is probably a good motivation to move things there. After all, you can also use this to get input on your team’s decisions and maybe iterate on it and improve it later (we all *always learn*).

It will be an issue however, if users end up asking support questions. I can imagine that having a jQuery team (to continue that example) will attract inexperienced users to ask questions there. After all, what’s more promising than asking the library developers directly about your beginner’s problem? Of course, this may be appropriate for very small team projects where the developers don’t think it’s good enough to ask on SO directly (although that really shouldn’t be the case), but for large projects that already have a large userbase and lots of participation on SO, I can certainly see this becoming a problem. So moderation is a very big point that needs to be solved. Otherwise, I can see a constant influx of annoying questions drive away teams.

As for the second use case, this is definitely attractive to companies wanting to show off; but it mostly works for open companies only. Stack Overflow is the prime example here: They serve a super large platform with an incredible amount of active users and content. Of course that makes the company very interesting to many developers, triggering questions about the architecture (*“how do you manage to do X?”*, *“Why did you decide to build your own Y for this?”*, …). After all, building and hosting Stack Overflow absolutely isn’t a simple task. And even for non-technical questions this still works well since Stack Overflow is very open about their work culture. Their belief in working remote is remarkable and I can certainly see this or other topics start many interesting questions that are also interesting to users not interested in applying there.

But this does not work for many other companies. Of course, we have some where I can totally see this; e.g. companies like Slack or Facebook using this as a platform to advertise themselves as possible employers. But most companies don’t work like that; most companies cannot go public about things for many reasons. Those reasons can include [corporate governance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_governance) or even just [NDAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) about customer projects. Of course, if you ask employees, they often want to be able to talk about things, but more often than not, they simply can’t. So for a company to participate in such a platform, there would be a lot going on in the background to make it work even remotely. And in the end, there will probably only a few people left in the position allowed to answer a certain kind of questions in some special way. And that makes it immediately less attractive.

So apart from the use cases, of which one is only very limited, I don’t really see what this platform is going to solve. What is it supposed to do for teams that don’t work like Stack Overflow?

Comment: While teams might not be able to talk about specifics, maybe they could still share broad lessons and insights—which is more than what's probably out there now. To your point though about how most companies don't work like this, maybe not. But more and more are opening up about things like team culture, projects, and members. These are the things other developers care about—especially if you are considering joining that team. And companies are starting to (slowly) recognize this.

Comment: What’s the incentive though for companies to share these broad lessons and insights? What do they get for investing time? And it’s very often not up to the companies to decide this. This is different for companies that create a product they can highlight (e.g. Stack Overflow). For example, the company I work for works for other companies. We simply are not in a position where we can decide whether we can talk about most of our projects publicly.

Comment: Could you talk about how your company runs projects for other companies or why your company suggest certain solutions over other ones to your clients? The incentive for companies—specifically—is recruiting. Developers are highly sought after (and I mean highly). There aren't enough developers for companies. When there is a demand supply issue then, companies need to do more to attract and engage developers—being transparent about the team culture, members, and projects is _one_ way to stand out (right now).

Comment: @Hynes: As I look through this whole page, one thing becomes clearer to me from the staff responses: that this is a misplaced Careers feature. Can you explain why SO needs or wants this as something separate, if it's main use is recruiting (already covered by Careers), and it doesn't really work for anything technical (reasons discussed by others like confidentiality, etc.)?

Answer (score 22):

This sounds like reddit. Each team gets their own <strike>sub-reddit</strike> Team where they can answer questions about their individual area of interest/expertise. Each area will have their [own administration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment255648_307534).

> At this point our current thinking is that Team admins will be able to self-moderate. If team admins become drunk with such power in their fiefdom, then we will have to address the issue at that time.

There are various comments throughout this post saying it's not going to be a social network. Unfortunately, that's not what it feels like.

---

> So... is this like a permanent AMA sort of thing? Where an employee (or group of employees) field questions from SO users about how they (technically) run their operations?  – [Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment255340_307513)

That's what it sounds like. Especially with comments like:

> - [Teams can share how they work and what they’ve learned.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/) - OP
> - [In some ways—yes, though Teams are bigger than just companies. LinkedIn is mainly about you. Your resume. Your network. A rolodex of people at a company. Teams is about people sharing about themselves. What do you build (or what are you working on)? What's the team culture like? What do you love about this team?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment255703_307513) – Hynes♦
> - [These are all great questions, so thanks for sharing. At this point what we like about team questions is that it's a way for people to inquire about a team. It's one aspect of Teams. It's not the aspect. We actually foresee projects being a bigger feature here. All the issues that you mention are valid concerns which we will need to explore the further we get into this. We're hesitant about laying down too many additional rules too quickly. Rules are meant to guide behavior, but before we can guide it, we want to understand how people use it first.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment255608_307560)  – Hynes♦

---

I can definitely see the benefit from the recruiting side. The posts throughout the thread that explain how SE (SO?) hopes this will be used to improve developer recruiting is a testament to what Stack Overflow has been about since the beginning - improving developers and making the internet a better place.

I just can't shake the social networking feel to this.

Comment: Could you define what you mean when you say "social network"? Because I think we have differing meanings here.

Comment: It feels like the AMA portion of reddit. Anyone can go ask a question that would normally be off topic on SO and the idea is the team will provide an answer. It may be a vague answer (ie "It cost a lot"), or specific (ie. "We bought X servers for this purpose, Y servers for this purpose and intend to purchase Z more if we meet our goals in the next few months."). It seems social in the sense that questions like "What's it work work there?" are being considered as appropriate. The idea of following a team - which SO doesn't let you do - "Focus on the content on the person" - seems very social.

Comment: There will still be off-topic questions and "too-broad" questions, even for team questions. We aren't welcoming vague answers either. As we move along we will have to implement methods to address this issue.

Comment: @Hynes Broadness wasn't the point being raised, I don't think. It's about *personalness* - "What do **you** do with X?" is a fundamentally more "social" question than "What can be done with X?". As Andy says, the focus is no longer on the content, it's on the person, who will inevitably be using it to advertise themselves.

Comment: @IMSoP: Well put.

Comment: @IMSoP: Maybe make that an answer.

Answer (score 18):

The idea of this sounds very interesting. From the sounds of it, it doesn't feel like it will fit the Stack Exchange Q&A model very well.

For starters (and correct me if I am wrong), giving each team their own Q&A page is almost like giving each team their own mini Stack Overflow site.  Which comes with all the benefits and baggage of a Stack Exchange site. The questions can be focused, informative and can be a great source of knowledge for all of us. However, I feel like there are a lot of potential problems here.

- Community size: One of the best parts of Stack Overflow is that if I ask a question, I am effectively asking a relatively large group of people that question. With such a large group, there is a at least fairly good chance I can find someone who has an answer. With Teams, I feel that since teams are going to be relatively small, the number of potential answerers is much smaller. And thus the chance of getting an answer is smaller. If getting an answer is conceivably harder, what is going to keep a community alive? Part of having a Stack Exchangesite go from being a proposal to a beta to a full fledged site (as I understand it), is being able to have enough activity and a large enough community to support that activity. Will small teams be able to handle that? Will large (and presumably very popular) teams be able to handle the tsunami of questions they get? I feel like some might hit the sweet spot between public interest and being able to answer questions and many won't.
- Culture fragmentation: what might be a good, answerable question for, say, the Google team, might not be for the Git team. What one team might be willing to answer will almost certainly vary from team to team (or able to answer, thinking mostly due to lawyers here, but there could be other reasons). This would lead to each team page having its own little sub-culture of what is a good question there and what isn't.
- Community moderation:  Stack Overflow's community moderation works because it has reached a sort of "critical mass" where there are enough people active to be able to combat the flood of spam and poor questions.  Will teams be able to achieve that "critical mass" of people to be able to moderate their own stuff? Will we just rely on everyone from all the teams to group moderate everything? How would that work if the previous point of team sub-cultures is a valid concern?
- The Q&A model and voting: Part of how Stack Overflow tends to accumulate some really, really good answers stems from being able to vote on answers and how good they are.  It can drive people to putting in a little more effort, to explain things better. It also allows more than one person to answer a question and have the best answers float to the top and the garbage sink to the bottom. With teams, I don't think there can be anything other than "the one true answer". Since the example questions seem to all ask about how teams do what they do, the only people that can really answer that are the team members. And there is no way for us to say "yes that answer is right" or "no it is wrong". It just kind of is what it is.
- Answers aren't timeless: If I ask on Stack Overflow how to write an SQL query in [SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) to do X, that will always work. It is also likely that I can take that knowledge into future versions of SQL Server and apply that code directly or at least the basic concepts. With teams, what is true today may not be true tomorrow. As teams learn from their failures or come up with new ideas, how they do things changes. Will answers be updated to reflect that? Or will we end up with a near innumerable number of "How does Team X do this as of Date Y?" questions?  Or, looking at one of the example questions: "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?". That kind of information is probably only good in a limited time frame and then quickly becomes obsolete.

I'm sure with enough thought I could come up with more concerns, but this is sufficient for now. Overall, I feel like this sort of thing is a better fit for a more traditional forum format than for the Stack Exchange model. I'm interested to see how this plays out, but I'm not very confident that it will be a rousing success.

Answer (score 18):

I don't find any of the given use cases compelling at all:

1. How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?",
2. "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?", or
3. "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?"

Why does company X want to answer question 1, and if they do, why do they want to do it in this tiny backwater of StackOverflow, rather than on their corporate blog?

Who really wants to ask question 2, other than senior operations manager at Y's competitor?

How is the answer to question 3 particularly specific to company Z, and what incentive do they have to answer it honestly? And again, who's asking it?

How do these questions not go out of date? How do they accurately reflect company-wide practices? Why does anyone want to write answers to what sounds mostly like fanmail. ("*Oh geez Acme Corp, you guys are so awesome, tell me how you run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale!*")

The way more plausible use case here is product support, which didn't even make your list of "possibly in the future", so I can only assume you really don't want Teams to be used that way.

Answer (score 17):

This doesn't sound appealing at all to me. There's one aspect that nobody addresses: Why the hell would I want to tell my competitors how I manage my remote teams and my infrastructure?

I am happy to answer questions on Stack Overflow because I know that I do it on a personal level. I know that even if I reveal my super-technique to achieve X to one of my fellow developpers, I am not giving away this information to my competitors. I can help people all over the world without helping my competitor, and this is the paradox that makes Stack Exchange fantastic and a place where people never hesitate to share.

Many people out there do not reveal the name of the company they work for in their profile. They only say: I work on this, this, and that, I like this, I do this in my spare time and have this many years experience. The people that are prompt to show their company names are in general consultants. So your stuff is a no-go for me.

The other thing is, it is not solving any problem for the user, it is solving a problem for you. You want to create a social network, and you came up with this first step. When Stack Exchange becomes a social network or a LinkedIn bis, my reputation points won't have any kind of value to me. I am going to post all my questions as a Guest, and if you remove the Guest feature, I'll create dummy anonymous accounts on a regular basis. If I want a social platform, they're already plenty of them out there.

What you're doing here guys is trying to change your brand. But a brand cannot be changed, it can only be destroyed. I've long been thinking: the Stack Exchange model is solid, and I'm not sure where they're getting their money, but what I'm sure of is as long as they are funded, I don't see what could make them close the boutique. After reading this post and connecting the dots with Career, I have much less problems to imagine an Internet without Stack Overflow in 10 years.

Comment: I don't really follow all the "social network" accusations that are being throwing around in this thread. Talking about technical things with our photo next to it is what we already do, no? And SO's Careers angle has been around since... forever. Even if they  implemented all their new ideas next month (and their only motivation were to satisfy their investors), would any of it actually be LinkedIn or Facebook-level evil? Hardly. But some fair points otherwise, especially about there being much fewer "teams" out there that are willing (or allowed) to share their internal workings

Comment: Maybe they were thinking of [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) where employees and founders from even high-profile companies share a surprising amount of details of how they are (or were) operating. Sample: *[How did Michael O. Church regain his career after Google?](https://www.quora.com/How-did-Michael-O-Church-regain-his-career-after-Google)*

Comment: Another example: *[How can some really large services (like Dropbox) afford to use Python as a primary language, if it's one to two orders of magnitude slower than other, compiled languages?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-some-really-large-services-like-Dropbox-afford-to-use-Python-as-a-primary-language-if-its-one-to-two-orders-of-magnitude-slower-than-other-compiled-languages/answer/Kostadis-Roussos)*: "At Zynga we did the math in 2011 and discovered that the per-user cost was less than 0.1 cents. I would be surprised and delighted if another vendor shared their data, but I doubt anyone will"

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like an interesting experiment.

You're casting this as a Stack Overflow project, which makes a lot of sense, but I hope you'll think about how it interacts with other sites from the start, even if you don't implement anything for a while (or ever).  For some teams, Server Fault or DBA or Programmers may be as relevant as SO, and sites like Quality Assurance or Project Management or The Workplace might also be relevant. I hope a team page could, ultimately, have visibility from, and questions on, other sites on the network too.

Comment: This is definitely on ours minds - there are communities we see it making sense and others where it doesn't. We're aiming for Stack Overflow first but by virtue of our multi-tenant architecture the other communities can be done "for free" if the styles and such are done and ready. We'll want to prove it out first, though.

Comment: Right, it makes sense to beta-test on one site, and SO is clearly the site.  It'd be sad to try to branch out later and find *then* that the architecture got in the way, though -- we don't want *different, unlinked* pages for the same team on multiple sites.  So the goal of my post here is long-term design and it sounds like you're already there, so cool.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

> Instead, we’re looking to provide a place for questions such as:
>
> - "How does [Company X] run PostgreSQL at an enterprise scale?",
> - "What's a typical budget for [Company Y] when they upgrade their data centers?", or
> - "How does [Company Z] keep their distributed team working together even though they’re spread across multiple time zones?"

I like the motivation of providing a space for these sorts of questions -- I agree that they come up a lot, are currently off-topic for SO, and could be of broad interest (for many companies I would find each of these questions more interesting than the average hot network post). Another sort of question I see all the time is "Why did [Open Source Software Project A] make [Design Decision B]?" Often these questions can only be answered by members of the project, and teams would give the opportunity to gain insights (assuming a team was formed for the project).

That being said, I think a key ingredient of this would be **letting teams control what are on-topic questions for the team**. If any question about the team is fair game, I would imagine we could pretty quickly veer into not-so-great territory (asking personal questions about individual team members comes to mind).

Comment: Yeah, I think this is gonna be essential; if nothing else, a team question that no one on the team will answer is just noise.

Comment: On the other hand, giving Teams *too much* autonomy over the question topics risks making this a back-door for creating your own Stack Exchange sub-site. There would have to be guidelines for what on-topic guidelines are on-topic, which is making my head hurt a bit.

Comment: @IMSoP yeah, some baseline rules seem in order, but I would imagine different teams will have very different questions they're willing to answer (in much the same way that different types of conversations are valid in different chat rooms). I think teams would need some autonomy over "team question rules" (just like chat rooms have their room rules).

Comment: Maybe chat is a reasonable analogue here, @josilber: you don't have to talk about programming all the time, but if you're creating a room to talk about nazi fetishes you can expect flags and deletion. OTOH, if your room is people talking about node and someone spams their PHP questions... You can kick 'em out, no questions asked.

Comment: @Shog9 I would be a happy camper if we had teams self-moderate like we do in chat (set the "team question rules" and kick those who don't follow the rules), coupled with normal moderation for clearly bad stuff (spam/offensive).

Comment: @josilber At this point our current thinking is that Team admins will be able to self-moderate. If team admins become drunk with such power in their fiefdom, then we will have to address the issue at that time.

Comment: I think the main problem is that any sensible company would answer those 3 questions with "that's none of your business".

Comment: @Lundin: See discussion at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment255887_307549) comment.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sure many teams would answer such questions (especially #3, which doesn't seem too sensitive) and many teams would not. That's the whole point of my answer -- teams should be able to control what questions are on topic.

Answer (score 12):

I foresee a large issue where a team starts up and is abandoned at some point. They stop answering questions. They stop adding members. They stop doing anything related to that team at all. In the end, it results in people asking questions that will never be seen nor answered.

My suggestion is relatively simple. After 30/60/90/whatever days of no questions answered (and, perhaps, having had questions asked during that period to avoid unpopular teams being flagged), a team is made inactive. The team page still exists and all the questions still exist, but no new questions can be answered and anyone viewing the page will be shown that this team is inactive and perhaps give a way to nudge them out of slumber (a way to send a notification to them, with strict limits on how many are actually sent out. Maybe 1 a week?).

This way, you don't end up with askers going to the team page for a company, asking how they handle something, and never getting a reply. It will happen, obviously, but this would minimize the chance of it happening repeatedly.

Comment: dunno... Kinda feel like this would happen quite often even for teams that are still active. Would certainly happen if i started one for my "team"

Answer (score 11):

**I'm concerned about the quality of Team Questions and how to handle them with minimal effort.**

Some Team Pages, from popular companies/projects, will attract tons of spammers and trolls. To avoid this, please, consider the following:

1. Meta requires 5 rep to post. Please, **set a rep requirement for posting Team Questions**, at least of 5-10 rep. [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307532/1476885) called the attention to the fact that some companies will create their pages and will disappear after the novelty wears off. If they'll not care about the quality of their Team Questions, neither will the community. So, to avoid trolls and spammers, please set a privilege for posting there.
2. Give **mod powers** for team members to be able to easily handle crappy Team Questions. If they own the Team Page and are worried about the quality of the questions, make their life easier with the power to close/delete questions. Requiring 6 spam flags to remove a post will suck.

> What if someone asks a coding question on a team page?
>   - There will be an easy way to move it into regular Q&A.

Yes! That's it! **Easy ways to get rid of off-topic content**.

Comment: I'm not sure a rep requirement for *asking* questions is the right gate for this; I'd much prefer a rep requirement for creating a team in the first place, since that demonstrates some commitment to actually **participating on Stack Overflow!** There are probably better ways to control spam/abuse from askers, starting with rate-limits (and the various detection mechanisms found in our existing system) and probably ending with the ability for team members to block specific askers entirely (which should of course feed into the same spam/abuse-prevention systems).

Comment: @Shog9, ok, I've lowered my rep suggestion to 5-10rep. Let's trust in the current SO mechanisms to avoid spam/trolls, but no rep requirement will be really bad. Some companies like Google/Apple/Microsoft will attract thousands of haters, trolls and "funny" people. I believe that will be much more that we are used to handle.

Comment: @Zanon We understand that we will attract spammers and trolls, and as issues arise we will address them. This is a private beta for now so all those rules don't need figured out _right_ now. They will need to be figured before we release this to everyone. To address the **mod powers** comment—team member admins will have "mod powers" for their team.

Answer (score 11):

## Disputes?

What if I create a Stack Overflow team, or GitHub team, or whatever team that I don't have anything to do with? Sure, this is easy if the impersonated company is famous, but that's not the case for everybody.

Do you have a way to handle disputes?

Comment: Yes, we will have a way to handle disputes. No, we don't have those details ironed out right now. _For now_ all we're looking to do is see how people would use Teams within a private beta. We'd rather test out how people use the feature first before racing to create rules around it based on how we _assume_ people will use it.

Answer (score 11):

If final authority on the content of a team's page is given to the team, many pages would likely fall below an acceptable quality level.

If final authority is given to the community, then surely many groups would choose to avoid creating a team page, for fear that it would expose content that they prefer not be public.

How can you mix community moderation with corporate ownership? Either the community is unable to uphold standards, or any company which creates a page exposes themselves to the risk of their message going off-track.

Comment: As I told [josilber yesterday](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/307578#comment255390_307534), I think chat offers a useful model here - everything is owned by its author, moderated by the room then the community.

Comment: @Shog9 But in this case, a company would hypothetically be pointing to its SO page from, say, its own website. And if someone followed that link and saw a valid question with a problematic answer (ie: company x doesn't have a procedure in place to deal with the risk of y), then who would delete it? Would the company have the right to delete valid questions, thus turning the whole thing into a bit of a marketing farce?

Comment: Good question - let's find out!

Answer (score 11):

I'm much more sceptical of this idea than of the documentation idea. The use case for this seems to be non-existent, and the example questions seem to cover nearly anything one would ask that would be of benefit to a wider community. If someone wants to ask something more specific then I hear email has really taken off.

Other than the questions the use is covered by a multitude of other services already available, meaning it would introduce fragmentation, not coalescence.

I just thought: Is this a way to replace Stack Exchange for companies? For example, such as a Ubuntu team on unix.stackexchange.com instead of askubuntu.org.

Comment: Which other services, for example?

Comment: Can you give me more info on this email thing you talk about? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @AlexHall *1. Q&A* -> covered my opinion by my original answer I believe.
*2. Show off professionally* -> careers.stackoverflow.com, linkedin.com, github.com, dribbble.com, I could continue ad nauseam.
*3. Hiring or recruitment* -> See 2 for the most part, there are a **lot** of fairly decent recruitment sites out there. The things left wrong with recruitment is, IMHO, down to recruiters and HR dept.s, not the online tools.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's something to do with this whole internet malarky. you might need one of those disks from AOL and a program called a browser (check your computer has enough RAM!) http://home.mcom.com/home/welcome.html

Comment: @Toby nah, I'm not getting into that. It's going to blow over in a year or two, mark my words.

Comment: @Toby *“The things left wrong with recruitment is, IMHO, down to recruiters and HR dept.s, not the online tools.”* – That’s so true. And I fear that this idea will just get those people directly on SO (into teams); and I’m not sure if that’s a good idea at all.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is a great idea. Let's assume my use case:

> I develop an opensource library and start working on it and other software with friends. However, none of us have still enough points to create a tag with the name of our library, so we can follow it and immediately answer questions about usage of our library. Having a team is the perfect place to point people to ask questions "If any question on usage arise ask on our team page on Stack Overflow".

The Stack Overflow voting system is much better than anything I saw on the web, and I would prefer to use a Stack Overflow page instead of using a [Google Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) group (it can still have its use of course).

Another nice feature would allow to see the combined reputation of all Stack Exchange sites on team pages (of course decreased by 100 for each site) that are marked pertinent to team page.

When you answer on a pertinent Stack Exchange site, you can choose one among the teams you belong to and use that as signature pointing to your team page.

That will automatically incentivate users to still answer and post questions just because that will may attract users to a team (well, many may dislike that because that's equivalent to spamming, but many users already spam "their library", and the signature size may change anyway, something like a small icon or text beside the name).

Comment: Except for the signature bit (maybe [in a user card](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)?), this is exactly right - I think a lot of folks struggle with this right now, and there's no obvious entrypoint for it. The tag thing is an aspect I hadn't even thought of, but is worth further consideration: what *are* we gonna do for tags in team questions?

Comment: I think a team could both import tags from related exchange sites, and create tags. I really like the feature of tagging issues on github with custom (and COLORED) tags in example. Definitely using custom tags would help for teams (how many tags are allowed and who is allowed to create tags within a team need certainly to be refined) maybe the limits on tags of the team may depend on how active the team is on related exchange sites?

Answer (score 10):

**Thoughts from the Perspective of a Startup Company**

I'm the co-founder of a funded tech startup.  Here are some of my thoughts regarding the pros and cons for Teams:

Pros:

- This is a channel for marketing your company by showing who you are and what you're capable of organically
- By participating, you show the team's attachment to the larger coding community
- This is also a channel for attracting talent
- If your team page is active, it could be used as a way to show traction to potential investors
- You can earn bragging rights in the geek community

Cons:

- If you sound canned in your responses or take an unpopular stance in your answers, you may lose SO interest
- There is a potential for flame wars between teams -- "we are so much better than company/team X"
- Worse than flame wars, if another team has incorrect information posted regarding your team, you are at their mercy for takedown without a standard for moderation.
- Team claims related to internal processes may be hard to substantiate.  For example, "Our algorithm is 5x faster than Google's."
- Operating system/text editor/programming language holy wars may erupt
- You may not be able to recover from an unforgiveable SO sin (insert negative John Skeet reference here -- misspelling on purpose)

That being said, I've signed up for the beta.  Among other things, I think it has the potential to become a repository for best team practices.

The first thing I'm going to do (if selected for the beta) is write a guide for what my team considers on topic questions.

I would also like the ability for the team to set the level of reputation it chooses to allow for posting questions

Comment: All your cons are things we'd like to avoid as well. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This seems very accurate from the view of a company, but it raises the question again: I see all the advantages for the companies, but I'm still missing the advantages to the SO community and broader developer community in general.

Comment: @Linuxios I think the advantage for the community from companies is in the collection and discussion of industry best practices.  The advantage for the community from open source projects are the questions like "Why did you do it this way?", which may lead to other projects. Finally, most of us work on a team and insight into how other teams work may help your team.

Comment: @Jesuisme: I understand. However, as far as I know "What is the industry practice for XYZ?" is considered on-topic already, assuming XYZ is a programming, and not a team-management problem, which would go to Workplace, or Programmers.

Comment: Good point Linuxios.  While there are some answers that will cover those questions, there are often nuances and departures from accepted practices that exist.  And I think we will find that even though we all code, different application areas have different styles, team dynamics, and "go-to" methods.  But you may end up being right in the end,  depending on how we use and respond to Teams.

Comment: @Jesuisme: Probably true. I guess the team is determined to go through with this though, so we'll find out!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this will work well for large organizations.  In your examples, you listed Microsoft Excel as a way for organizations to break into more manageable team sizes.  Well, I work on a big product along with hundreds of other people.  But I don't think the product itself would make for a good team.

I don't know most of those people and I doubt they know me.  We'd just be a mass of hundreds of faces in a crowd, not really a great representation of "who is working with you" nor a good way to indicate to job applicants what their team would be like.  Even though there are some commonalities across groups in a large company, some aspects of the culture can vary all the way down to the manager level.  Some technical solutions may even vary because different groups have different priorities.

I believe it would be difficult to provide general answers to questions, and it's likely you'd end up with only a handful of users on a large team actually answering them, if we were even allowed to answer them at all.  Many things we simply couldn't discuss or would need official approval.

At the same time, I think creating teams at the feature level (which more closely aligns with the group of coworkers I associate with) would result in a lot of teams that are too small. Looking around the SE network, for many feature teams there just isn't a high volume of existing Q&A traffic for those features, which suggests there wouldn't be a lot of public interest for their teams here.  You'd also end up with a lot of duplicate questions cross-posted across the team sites.

What kind of team size are you expecting would benefit from this most?

Comment: What would you consider a team that is too small? We imagine most teams will be smaller (15 people or less) and most likely within the 2-5 person range. Also why is that too small? The team's content will not _only_ be questions. It's one of many content types we're considering.

Comment: @Hynes Small teams make the fragmentation that people are fearing even worse. If every group of 2-5 people can make up their own Q&A moderation rules, publish their own choice of "artifacts", etc, it's going to be hard to cultivate a community *between* teams, and that feels very alien to the open, collaborative, Stack Exchange model.

Comment: @Hynes Small teams in and of themselves aren't necessarily bad.  But breaking a large product into smaller teams would create a lot of duplication and confusion.  I'd say 2-5 people is about the size I'm thinking of, but depending on employee SO participation, you could have anywhere from a dozen to two hundred feature teams for one product.  That's kind of a logistical headache - people asking questions to the wrong team, managing shared content and keeping it in sync across teams, keeping everything up to date, preventing ghost towns as employees transfer across teams or leave, etc.

Comment: @IMSoP Why would we allow every group to make up their own mod rules?

Comment: @Troyen if we have 12-200 teams for 1 product then we will gladly find a way to address the issues you mention. Teams becoming "ghost towns" is a concern, but a team also does it to their own detriment. It's how they appear on SO. They created the page. If they choose to ignore it, doesn't that tell you something about the team? If these areas become a bit long in the tooth, then the product team needs to find ways to engage those teams again.

Comment: @Hynes Have you actually read the other discussions on the page? It's been repeatedly stated that teams will be moderators in their own page, and free to set On-Topic rules for their own Q&A.

Answer (score 9):

> When a new question is created, the team will be notified through
>   their inbox that a new question has come in. [...] Once notified,
>   anyone **on the team** can answer the question. 
>   [emphasis mine]

If I understand correctly, this means that *only* team members will be allowed to answer questions and also to edit answers? (Note that if this assumption is false, then the rest of this answer is superfluous. Anyway - this important aspect should certainly be mentioned more explicitly in the proposal.)

If this is true, then the team feature seems to me a bit like a mini Stack Exchange site, where only moderators may answer questions. Not that this is necessarily a bad thing, but it is something that should be reasoned about. After all one of the main reasons for the success of Stack Overflow and the high quality Q/A is, that both questions *and* answers get created and moderated entirely by a community-driven process of thousands of people.

Some aspects to consider:

- How would the quality of the answers scale, if only a handfull of team members are allowed to answer and edit answers?
- What happens, when a team member leaves the company of the team - will she still be able to answer questions? Will she still be able to edit *her* answers?
- Let's say there is a question about a specific library a team developed, and the accepted top answer is actually only promoting the awesomeness of said library. Would I, as a user of the library, have some way of proposing an answer that relativates this from a user perspective? If yes, who would decide if an answer is a good fit for the team site? The (most likely biased) team members? The moderators?
- If information gets outdated - will I, not being a team member, be able to propse edits to update an answer? Who is deciding if an edit gets accepted?
- Will everyone have the ability to flag answers, vote for close/reopen etc? Again - who has the last say?

Not that I am too concerned about all that - I think the team feature could provide very interesting and useful functionality for the community if done right.

Comment: These are all great questions, so thanks for sharing. At this point what we like about team questions is that it's a way for people to inquire about a team. It's _one_ aspect of Teams. It's not _the_ aspect. We actually foresee projects being a bigger feature here. All the issues that you mention are valid concerns which we will need to explore the further we get into this. We're hesitant about laying down too many additional rules too quickly. Rules are meant to guide behavior, but before we can guide it, we want to understand how people use it first.

Comment: Sounds like SO trying to be LinkedIn and searching for revenue opportunities while careers.stackoverflow.com is languishing.

Answer (score 9):

**Should I add this thing to stackoverflow.com?** *This thing being teams.*

Does it help people ask questions?  *No.*

Does it help people find answers when their question is already asked?  *No.*

Does it help answerers find questions they can answer?  *No.*

Does it help answerers answer the question correctly?  *No.*

Does it help peers to determine the validity of an answer?  *No.*

I don't ask questions on Facebook, and I don't intend to have a friends list on Stack Overflow. Teams add nothing to our ability to ask, answer, and review questions, and questions and answers add nothing to teams. If you want teams, and you can think of some way you can do it better than Facebook and Google do it already, better than teams do it themselves already, start a brand new intellectual property for it.

Comment: What is "IP" in this context? Intellectual property? Domain name?

Comment: @petermortensen yes, fixed.

Comment: I'd argue that teams do add something with regard to reviewing questions etc, but it's not good. Teams are a great way to pool together votes, the currency that drives most of the actions here. When you pool them together, you can have a team that has a strong, erroneous opinion about question X and wield their friends list to close it or completely obliterate it (delete), provided there is high enough rep users in the group. This happens frequently with chat. People share links to things they don't like, and people blindly follow and destroy it.

Comment: @technikempire good point.  The system for distributing ethos and gravitas on stackoverflow is great as is, no need to complicate it.

Answer (score 8):

## How will this expansion impact Stack Overflow's current SEO?

Currently, Stack Overflow results dominate Google search results for programming problems. One of the reasons why localized questions aren't allowed on the site is because *they aren't useful to a general audience*. Otherwise, search results would be cluttered with solutions that could really only help the person who originally asked the question, and no one else. ["*Finish writing the rest of my code to solve my particular problem*"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32857540/2) questions are a classic example.

**I'm concerned about how allowing localized questions in Team sections of the site will affect SO's overall search rankings.** Suppose I'm trying to figure out general techniques for optimizing my queries in SQL Server. I search Google, and the top result ends up being a non-technical answer about how Team XYZ on Stack Overflow optimized their database queries by outsourcing to consultants, because it was more cost effective for them? That probably won't be of much help to me...and that's just one example of how SEO could be negatively affected.

This expansion reminds me so much of questions that I'll sometimes find on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) (and perhaps Reddit too). I never see Quora dominating search results, but maybe I'm just not searching for things where Quora dominates.

Comment: In your scenario, maybe one result is how a team outsourced their problem, but you could also have a number of other answers how various teams optimized their SQL Server for specific circumstances—which line up potentially with some of your circumstances. The short answer to your initial question is we don't know, but if that becomes an issue then we'll address it when the problem is more fully formed.

Comment: I do see Quora pollute the top of my search engines searches every now and then, [sadly](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Quora#Concerns).

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** As a question-poster, `post-with-tags` is more useful than `post-to-team-page`.

Best explained with an example:

I'm facing an issue - OS-X specific, using Python 3.4, anaconda and a third library (both with github pages). Right now, I start a post-with-tags under stackoverflow.com (tagging **`python`**, **`OS-X`**, **`anaconda`** etc).

This would then attract answers from people who have worked with similar library groups, and people who have developed individual libraries, as they would presumably be following those tags or have them recommended due to their interaction history.

Assuming that in 3 months, each library has a team page, this convention changes... I can `post-with-tags`, `post-on-team-page` or `post-with-tags-on-each-team-page`... essentially being forced into classifications where none is needed.

A far more useful alternative to **Teams** would be to allow each person/ID to optionally have additional expert-level tags (like Twitter's Verified ID) next to their user-name.

Comment: To put it another way.... (i) a posting under **Teams** implies that it is most relevant, when it might not be. (ii) if posted under a wrong team / if  (unrelated) teams are required to cooperate to solve compatibility/interaction issues, classifying something under one team is disadvantageous.

Answer (score 7):

## Never change a winning concept!

While I liked the idea for a second, the **BIG** problem quickly dawned upon me: SO/SE isn’t a team-site… just like it isn’t a forum (even when truckloads of newcomers a day tend to “think different” and cause havoc by posting comments as answers, and all that fun stuff).

Now, don’t get me wrong on this – I sure love collaboration and I‘ve spend my fair share contributing to loads of open-source projects as a dev so I know what *team* means – but from my experience, when people start to team up, it doesn’t take long until one team tries to get (let’s just call it) stronger than any other team. Therefore, I think things have a big chance going south quickly. When people have a chance to group up, it simply introduces a new dynamic… and the reality of the internet is that such a dynamic isn’t really positive (or healthy) in each and every way.

Providing only one of many examples: it is to be expected that a single person answering a question correctly might be overrun and most probably downvoted by a group of (as they’ll call themselves)…

[image: “experts”]

… just because the team wants to remain the “best at” or wants to be displayed as “we know it all, forget the rest”. Surely this won’t happen in each and every situation, but the potential scenarios exist.

Closely related with this comes another thing: “peer pressure”, which can result in a team member going against her better judgment to escape the wrath of other members. The result at SO/SE would be a bad answer quality… which would be bad for the related SE site, and the SE network as a whole.

While I’m pretty sure the SO/SE core team is aware of such issues (after all, those are the areas where *gamification* can and – according to Murphy’s law – will go wrong if not handled correctly), and while I’m pretty sure the SO/SE core team already has some ideas to stop potential “unite and conquer” strategies by yet-to-be-implemented *teams*, I can’t say I’m having an easy feeling when thinking about the potential badness that might get introduced with such a feature. May be me, but this is one of those rare times where my gut feeling prevents me from saying “hey, that’s a great idea”. Honestly, I currently think it’s not.

Yet, I’m open to be proven wrong. In fact, I hope I’m wrong… because I just love the SE network.

Answer (score 6):

> What if someone asks a coding question on a team page?
>   There will be an easy way to move it into regular Q&A.

I'm more concerned about how it will work the other way around. Right now there are tons of questions that are off topic on main Q&A site but would fit individual team's Q&As like you said.

Do we let team members "steal" questions from main site? Do we get a voting system like for closing questions? Can all people participate in that voting or only team members?

What happens to any rep gained or lost on those Q&As, or more importantly what about down-votes which might often happen on off topic questions that would never get down-voted on team pages?

Comment: We have no plans for regular Q&A being converted to team questions. As for the "who can vote" on closing/deleting, we haven't really talked about that since the default assumption is "everyone" and we haven't seen any reason that'd change. We haven't gotten heavy into close reasons, but the list would be different, because of what's on/off-topic for example.

Comment: @NickCraver I meant in case it was possible to migrate from regular Q&A, who would have the power to do so? You should really reconsider that since I don't think it's a less complicated problem that getting new users to post in proper place. It would be much more useful to have migration from regular to team Q&As and just delete/close off topic questions on team sites than the other way around (much more useful for teams that is).

Comment: This way you are giving teams burden of moderating off topic questions and moving them to regular site, but aren't giving them a chance to answer questions posted to regular site because they would just be closed as off topic.

Comment: @FilipRadelic I defer to Nick here, but if we were to consider something like this I would imagine that team members would not be able "grab" questions out of the community area to answer on their page. Team members are mods for their page—not the community.

Comment: If it team related questions beginning flooding the community area, maybe a migration path could be built used by mods to move them over. The problem is that 1) a team page might not always exist, 2) a mod might not _which_ team to address this to (which becomes a bigger issue if it goes to the wrong team), and 3) there might already be a similar question there.

Answer (score 6):

Would there be a risk of company profiling?

If you have developers openly linked to companies/projects it makes it possible to analyse the questions they are asking and speculating on their future intentions.  I could see this being an issue across many companies, large companies (media speculation) and start-ups (IP protection during early development).

Also, if you are publicly associated with a company then every answer you provide is potentially a reflection on the company, this could be difficult for developers and management to balance.

It sounds like it could be 'too transparent' in practice.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't adding a cool new feature, it's an attempt to replace the cornerstone of SO, the individual.

What has driven this site is individuals asking questions and individuals sharing their knowledge. This is the focus, it's because you have so many individuals posting individual content that you have all of the content that you do. Now you want to put the focus on groups.

Let's remember that groups can be blamed as one of the pillars of division and conflict in the world. When I'm in group A and you're in group B, it's you VS me, no matter how politically correct and heavily policed that environment is. In Canada right now (where I'm from) we're voting day minus 1, and a great way to start world war 3 is for me to simply step outside and publicly declare what group I support. Sure, this isn't the exactly the same, but a group is what a group is, a line in the sand drawn between you and me.

As it stands, we're all of one group. We're individuals all contributing our knowledge independently and together, for the (usually) harmless competition of collecting rep. However, a great many fights (moderators and experienced users will know this) have come along over even silly internet points or just pride. I submit that people are far more motivated and willing to go to battle or do evil in the name of their clan than for fake internet points (see all of human history for references).

I've already said this but I'll say it clearly: this discards the individual, which is what we're all about, and you know it, hence the language to attempt to make them appear included.

> Teams are self-forming. We aren’t going to create them. That’s up to
>   you. They can be of any size…even 1 person.

I am a jack of all trades, I can do most of the work of a complete team, but that still doesn't make a team. One person isn't a team just because you put "Team" next to their name. You're trying to be inclusive but (not trying to be rude) it's nonsense, team/individual are polar opposites and one of these is going to become a second class citizen.

Finally, even if you omit everything I've already said, the example questions you give are off topic and I think it would be a minority who would really care about the answers and surrounding discussion. I come here when I'm in cargo cult mode and can't understand why something unexpected is happening in something new, to find detailed, educating discussion **about code** so I can learn **about code**. I don't care how X Billion Dollar Corp Inc. scales Y software across N servers and what the budget is, because that has little do **with code** and more about systems administration.

Further, seeing that I don't sit at the helm of a billion dollar business looking to scale up my infrastructure to serve my 70 million customers, I simply don't care. Did I mention this website is **about code**?

Answer (score 3):

Be warned:

You will reduce Stack Overflow to a few cliques of self-proclaimed experts talking to each other.

The questions from students on Stack Overflow will be ignored by these cliques or simply not seen as they focus on trying to impress each other within the cliques. Stack Overflow's greatest value, viz., solving simple problems quickly, will be greatly diminished.

Moreover, I bet that most of your users started with Stack Overflow during their neophyte days and used it most heavily during that period. If you diminish and exclude them, you are diminishing your future role.

I could be wrong about this, but I could be right. Seems like a very bad business move

....and yes, I agree with other responses here, that you are followimng the herd on social media trends.

Comment: _"I bet that most of your users started with Stack Overflow during their neophyte days"_ I was going to berate you for suggesting that "most" users would either be young enough or stupid enough to have built their career on SO usage, but I realised I scarily have no data to back that up, and there _are_ a lot of young SO users. Like, a lot. If you started programming within the last five years or so I suppose there's a chance you're one of them. But let's not forget that the real experts who create the technology you use in the world learnt their trade _long_ before Stack Overflow came about.

Comment: acknowledged....and heaven forbid that SO is used in place of solid training. But most neophytes nowadays rapidly learn to rely on SO for fixing IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, transaction problems etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

How will migrated questions be handled? Will the migrater be the owner, or the original asker, or the team, or something else? Any of those *could* have a negative effect.

**Original asker**

They asks a valid question for a team, and someone (wrongly) decides to move it to Stack Overflow where actually, it's off-topic. Then, though no fault of the asker, they get downvoted, flagged, etc.

**Migrater, Team, Community, and Other**

The question is a good valid Stack Overflow fit, well received, get's good answers, and a lot of attention on up-votes. This way the original poster misses out on the reputation points, badge progress, etc. that comes with asking a good question.

The only thing I can think is there is some sort of approval queue for questions being migrated, or they default to Community, and the asker gets a notification saying "Your questions has been migrated, do {{this thing}} to claim it". That way if the question was badly migrated, the user can ignore it, but if it is a good one, they can get the rewards that come with asking a good question.

Answer (score -5):

More and more I realize that it takes great effort and a bit of luck to get one idea across. People has different interests, and they tend to "translate" information toward their own interests. Back in June 2015, I was trying to find a chance to present one idea to facilitate collaboration in a conference, but I did not manage. Now I am on adrenaline to see @Hynes present the idea here. Let's see what we can do together.

I call it the MBL (music band like) collaboration model. The motivation is very much the same if you don't want to call it identical. I was focusing more on [bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics), but aiming at a more general solution. It is to solve a software project, biology project, or any other projects that need expertise that you can't find around you, or you do not satisfy with the current situation. I thought about advertising the idea to Stack Overflow and establish my first "band".

I registered some domains and intended to find partners to develop the idea further. However, there have been other things with higher priority to finish. And now, I see it is an excellent time to talk about it. I do not intend to hijack the topic, but I want to show I share the same vision. I will be delighted to talk and find the collaboration if someone is interested. I post some slides below, if you are interested in the whole presentation; contact me via email.

To comment on the Opening Post, as you may already know by now, I am with it. However, I truly believe in terms of "branding", Stack Overflow needs to have a sister brand for this kind of service, i.e. another sub of Stack Exchange.

[image: Title]

[image: Five Pillars]

[image: MBL Moble]

[image: BiSSt]

**Update:**

In reply to some comments, I would like to clarify what I am trying to say. I was thinking about making a website to offer a platform for people with various professional background to assemble a team with expertise that he/she is looking for. This platform is to address the need to create a collaboration that is driven by professional background, project's needs/goals, and openly discussed benefits for everyone involved. I use the metaphor of a music band (slide #3 top down) to describe the way this team is assembled or disassembled.

As far as I can see, the new service being proposed here by Hynes has much similarity to the platform I am incubating. For example, both allow team formation from site's members, QnA among team members.   However, I aim at an dedicated website and not limited to programming projects. A separate website, even though it may share user database and login session, offers various other benefits, such as:

1. working on various types of projects, including non-coding projects.
2. private discussion for project's sensitive information an
3. unambiguous identity for branding and SEO and room for adding other
4. functionality as online collaboration tools.

If StackOverflow staffs and anyone else are interested, I will be glad to join force and build the website.

Hope this make things clearer, and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Maybe you should make clearer what you're trying to say here; what is your goal with this? Where do you see a connecting point between your idea and Teams, and how is it relevant to SO?

Comment: Heck is this gibberish?

Comment: LightnessRacesinOrbit , @Pekka웃 and Boann, I added an update at the end of the post. Please be patient while I am trying to improve my writing skill :-)

Comment: Your idea is interesting, but I'm not sure whether it's going to be compatible with this Teams thing - it seems to go beyond what they are proposing, and they're getting loads of flak for introducing social networking elements as it is... For a right-out job application, you should probably write to the team directly

Answer (score -8):

There are teams on the SE sites already. Inofficially. Most of the SE sites are controlled by an inbreed team calling itself "community".

The proposed "expansion" of the SO won't be an expension, it will make them only fair and legal. Essentially, you would only legalize the voting circles.

Instead of it, maybe you should work on some other areas:

- Making the new profil page ready, integrating it to the other parts of the system (here I am thinking on especially to the consistent support of the hidden accounts)
- Restart of the suspended area52 project (the update & expansion of area51)
- Constructing some organisational and technological idea to better support on the multilingual (i.e. non-English) sites
- Helping the different SE sites better integrated, for example easier question migration or even shared content between the different SE sites.

On my opinion, you should go into these directions and not into the current one.

Answer (score -24):

I was very excited.

Then I saw the part where you wouldn't allow private teams.

Comment: Care to expand on this a bit? Do you have a particular concern with the disallowing of private teams? Or it is just your personal preference that teams be private? If you expand on your idea here, the team can more easily address it.

Comment: Just to be clear, "private teams" seems to just mean you can't form teams that are hidden from public view. It doesn't mean that individuals can't form a team. If you are looking for an internal team communication tool there are vastly better options out there than SO could ever offer you.

Comment: That is to make sure SO's infrasystem does not get abused as a private code sharing base. There are existing services to do just that.

Comment: @Jongware it's not that - it's that private teams doesn't go towards our goals of expanding knowledge. If the artifacts aren't public, what good are they to the world at large?