# Yelow background on questions

Tags: discussion

About an hour ago qestions feed appear with yellow background on some questions. What does it mean?

Comment: Did you recently answer the [questions asked on your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information), including adding favorite tags? If so, the hone page will now show you (via highlighting) the questions in your favorite tags.

Comment: Yes I did answer question in my profile regarding where I work and if I am looking for work etc. 3 questions

Comment: [Check out this MSE post about favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do).  The new profile questions were to encourage users to add some favorite tags which help with the overall experience by highlighting questions that you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry all. I was searching for yellow background and nothing was found. Actually that was old question, but why stack has added that feature just 1 hour ago for me? I am 2 years hear.

Comment: They didn't, you must have just recently added favorite tags.

Comment: @tnw, no. 1 hour ago I saw a message that stack is improoving profile and I can answer some questions. After I answered some questions begun backgrounded yellow. Why I got that message after 2 years then?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri That message was just released today - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information

Comment: @bluefeet, ok I got it now. Thanks all for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means it's tagged with one of your favorite tags. If you have `C#` and `java` as favorites, and you're in `java` for example, a question which is also tagged with `C#` will be highlighted. If you're just on the main feed, any question with one of your favorite tags will be highlighted.