# Unclear functionality in new profile features

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I got the new profile features popup today. The second page about tags is unclear:

[image]

1. What does 'Pick a few tags' do? The *will help us show you...* is vague<sup>*</sup>.
2. Is the input box for *adding other* tags?
   You can type the tag titles and have them auto-complete as usual; that includes tags already displayed (looks like the current list of favorite tags). I thought I was supposed to drag tags to the edit control (red arrow), but this gave me a URL in the inputbox (default browser behavior)
3. I clicked a red cross in a tag and it disappeared from the list. Is this supposed to happen (why: point 1)? It did not change anything to my favorite tags on the front page.

<sup>* It immediately triggers a red flag for me, I have seen too many of these 'helpful' offers from LinkedIn, Facebook and the likes</sup>