# "Got it! We won't bother you with this anymore" on profile page — what was it?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, user-interface

When I went to my profile page, a nicely-designed display box was shown in place of the information I was after, but it wasn't relevant to what I was doing at that moment, so I clicked the "Not now" button in its top right corner.

The profile page then displayed as normal, with an extra message saying something like

> Got it! We won't bother you with this anymore.

Normally a 'not now' / 'ask me later' option will defer the interaction to a later time, but this message suggests my momentary wish has been made permanent. (I don't see anything to reverse it; even the message has gone.)

At the risk of indulging [FoMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_missing_out), what exciting opportunity have I so carelessly tossed into the abyss? Was it intended to be a one-time-only deal — perhaps an early hat? When does 'not now' mean 'not ever'?

(Tagging as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because what happened was unexpected, though of course I can't reproduce it.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was the box you saw:

[image]

It exists to inform you of a few extra fields on your profile:

If you *had* clicked the "get started" button, you'd have seen something like this:

[image]

Followed by this:

[image]

Aaand then this:

[image]

These correspond to fields that are *always* available in [your profile editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) (where you code, job situation) and [your site preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) (favorite tags).

So even if you dismiss that box with the "not right now" option, you can always go back to your profile later on and set up the same preferences. The "wizard" thing just exists as a way to let you know that [something new was added to the profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information).

Comment: If we must suffer these attention grabbing antics might I suggest the way to make clear the "exciting opportunity" hasn't been "tossed into the abyss" would be a simple animation that, on closing, shrunk and whisked the box over to where the fields actually are.  Some of us prefer to drive rather than be driven.

Comment: That would be cool. [meta-tag:feature-request]?