# Why can I only enter one job in my profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Stack Overflow just asked me to upgrade my account, providing information like where I program (my job) and stuff like that. I have two programming jobs, but there is only space for one. I guess this is a feature request: Allow entering more than one job.

Comment: I believe this is on the list for a future release.

Comment: @AdamLear It also looks like it's a choice between work or school, I would guess that for many it would be both, work and school.

Comment: @apaul34208 [Indeed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310172/3614835)

Comment: We're currently building this :)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin You had one job. :D