# When asking for my personal information, please be more open about what it's used for

Tags: discussion

I remember a Poll a while back, about the *quality of the site* or something like that, but the more questions you answered, the more things about *you as a person* were asked (age, job, interests..). It was sort of sly, but also kind of obvious, so I never completed the survey.

Today, when I logged in, I saw I could enhance my profile. Nice, why not.

The first question was what type of visitor I was (school, work, just love to code). It instantly made me a little suspicious again. And this is what the second step looks like:

[image]

Seriously, is it really just to 'show you much more relevant questions and answers', (which I do not doubt) or do you just forgot to say '**and show you more relevant ads and career options**'?

Edit: Lots of downvotes, didn't expect that.. Note that I never questioned that they are indeed using it to improve the site for me, I believe that. I'm also not a 'tin foil hat' kind of guy which doesn't to give personal information. See how I'm using my *real name*? I'm just wondering why they aren't telling you your information is also used for ads and careers (which are ads)

Comment: You don't have to do any of these things. It's your choice to provide this information.

Comment: That's not my point. My point is they should be honest about why they need it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Developer Survey and the "profile enhancement" feature you're talking about both come with pages on the site where the information usage is described in detail. The developer survey is a developer survey; the results (which exclude any identifying information about participants) are public data. As for the Profile Enhancement questions, those go to your user profile, IIRC; it's described in the Careers FAQ what information they pull from your user profile.

Comment: Also, if you've ever seen ads on Stack Overflow, you need to verify your installation of AdBlock Plus.

Comment: The careers are ads too, don't be naieve.

Comment: Yes, this site *will* collect information about you and use it to display targeted ads.  Whether it is done through this dialog is not very relevant, they can also see it by profiling what kind of questions you look at and answer.  It is a business, they are trying to make a living, that's not much of a secret.  At least you won't have to look at crap that is totally irrelevant to you.

Comment: I know, and I don't care. I actually work for a marketing company (see, I don't mind giving personal information). I'm just mentioning they're only telling you one side of the story, which just happens to be the part that makes you eager to fill in the forms ("enhancing your experience on the site").

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal but it really does enhance the site experience. In multiple aspects.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I never said I don't want to give my personal information. I'm just asking they should be a little more honest when asking for it.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal but they are being honest.  "_Seriously, is it really to 'show you much more relevant questions and answers',_" yes it really is.  I use the feature and it works very well.

Comment: The thing I'm wondering is, who cares? I use the Internet all the time, and I see targeted ads quite a bit. I don't really care that much about them unless they intrude on my browsing experience. I know that if I elect to give Stack Overflow this information, that they'll use it to tailor my ad experience and Careers profile, but *I trust them to do so without intruding on my SO experience in general*.

Comment: If your main concern is the lack of transparency in how SO uses your information, then I'm sure SO will respond in kind with a blog post detailing exactly where and how this is used, as well as FAQ entries making the process as transparent as possible. EDIT: As for your title, I think the message you were trying to send about the lack of transparency got lost in the inflammatory nature of the language you were using.

Comment: Re your edit: This would go a lot better with a less accusatory title.

Comment: Yeah, you may not have meant to accuse them of lying but that's what the "Seriously, is it really..." line sounds like.

Comment: Trivia: tag preferences have traditionally been a poor way of targeting ads; the system tracks what topics you actually *read*, and that's a lot more accurate (and less intrusive) than trying to *ask* everyone for the same information. An ad-focused system would probably do better with the UI attached *to the ad*, not to your profile. That said, I suppose in a round about way this can affect ads: if you set your preferences such that you only look at questions in those topics afterwards, *eventually* you'll get ads targeted at those topics because you're reading more of them.

Comment: I've updated my question. Also, again, I don't mind giving personal information, I don't mind ads, I don't mind *targeted ads*. I'm only wondering why they aren't telling you they use that info for the career platform, which are essentially ads.

Comment: If they're only telling one side of the story (which coincidentally happens to be the part that's positive for the user), they're essentially tricking you. @Yannis The title was meant to be 'accusatory', though you're probably right. I've updated the title.

Comment: Of course they're might use whatever information you input to target the content that is served. You as a marketer should expect that. Why should that be explicitly stated on every input field, and every question you visit?  It's just clutter that will lead to alarming users of something they shouldn't be alarmed about.

Answer (score 8):

These questions were [announced several weeks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information) ago as a way to show off a bit more about who you are as a developer.  Using the favorite tags does actually enhance the way you see the main page of Stack Overflow.  The point of these questions is to improve the profile for both new and experienced users.

Comment: I've never doubted that.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal All the questions are completely optional, you don't need to fill in anything so there really aren't any tricks here.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal, sounds like a miscommunication - it seemed like you did doubt it'd enhance how you see the main page where you said, "Seriously, is it really to 'show you much more relevant questions and answers?"

Comment: That's miscommunication on my part too, then. I'll add the word 'Only' in that sentence.