# What is Just <3 code?

Tags: support, profile-page

On my profile page there is the a setting for your career. It has three options, work, school, and Just <3 code. What is Just <3 code? I have never heard of it and tried googling it to no avail.

Comment: "Enthusiast" would be the less confusing name.

Comment: Or the use of ❤️.

Comment: It looks like an ice cream cone that has fallen over ... ;)

Comment: If your career is just 2 code then that satisfies the <3 requirement.

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307755/4428462), which I posted when it was first introduced. I was also somewhat puzzled..

Comment: Welcome to the internet, where people <3 to invent weird symbols, acronyms and abbreviations. It's a scary place, really.

Comment: @Hans http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317996/560648

Comment: Just ice cream code.

Comment: w<3schools, obviously.

Comment: Stupidicons.   Sigh.  Now I suppose somebody will want to add all these sequences to Unicode as single code points.

Comment: You did not [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%3C3%22%20meaning) hard enough.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: the ♥ is one of the oldest unicode characters…

Comment: In context of a profile page (e.g. from a Python forum) with the three options you mentioned I would read this as: nerd, hobbyist, enthusiast. In contrast to work or school you do it because you love it.

Comment: it means that just is smaller than three times code

Comment: Not something I'd expect grown-ups to be confronted with.

Comment: @SalmanA That assumes they know `<3` is an emoji, rather than the phrase `Just <3 code` being a common phrase. Searching `Just <3 code` gives no real results (except a link back to this question).

Comment: Tylerh answered it best, we <3 `Love` Coding-

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It means you just love to code, not necessarily for work or for school. The <3 characters represent a heart symbol (❤️), which means "love".

Comment: I was wonder why all those Facebook users were talking about "less than three"-ing each other on the 14th... :)

Comment: Points of view, IMO. If you see it from a certain side, it's a heart (so, "love"). On the other side, I do see a butt (so, "dumb ass").

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan text to speech programs with that kind of lines are funny, It must be annoying to blind people who uses those software.

Comment: I'm sorry but <3  just looks like a pair of balls to me... why am I the only one?

Answer (score 15):

I use the "Just <3 Code" option on my profile, it lets you type your own text for your profile.

As I have more than one "job" and currently you can only display one on your profile, I select the "Just <3 Code" option and enter the text "Full Stack ASP.NET Developer". This is then shown on my profile page rather than just one job.

Comment: It's a strange choice, yes... I code both for work _and_ as hobby. Selecting "Work" just makes it seem like a job and nothing else...