# I can't unclick from "Just <3 Code" because of the helpful popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I assume because of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317919/what-is-just-3-code), the popup below was implemented:

[image]

However, I now cannot click on either of the other options because of the popup. This is Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome 49.0.2623.108.

Comment: As an immediate workaround, if your browser supports HTML element editing (Like Firefox, which has the right-click option "Inspect Element"), then you can use it to delete the popup.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Nice point - I refreshed the page as I'd not entered anything anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved the tooltip to the side of the input box to avoid obscuring the buttons.

Fixed and being deployed.

Comment: Can't check now :P

Comment: So, you have a [meta-tag:status-norepro]?

Comment: I was making a little joke is all