# Stack Overflow doesn't love us anymore? :(

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, email

Today I noticed something horrible in  email about developer story/Jobs I got from Stack Overflow:

> [image]

Compare it with old email:

> [image]

Now you see what I mean?

Can the symbol of love please be added back to emails?

<3

Comment: [feature-request][bug]

Comment: @BoltClock hmm?

Comment: Or should it be replaced with `</3`

Comment: Nothing just thought the juxtaposition of those tags was amusing and ironic.

Comment: @George nah, just bring back the good old <3. :D

Comment: @BoltClock well, it might be a bug (they changed the email system, overlooked that part), and might be on purpose so wanted to catch both options in one place. :)

Comment: It was removed on purpose. We felt it looked out of place. We do still love you though.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson all other emails from SE still have it, e.g. tag subscription emails.

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually, it goes to everyone else - it is just you we don't... ok, ok, I'm kidding here, don't look at me like that!

Comment: @Marc you have the power... power of love... it can beat that evil decision...  :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard with my undying **death-defying love for you**... oh, sorry, I slipped and fell back into the 80s there.... *sparkling light, flowers and pearls and pretty girls* - dammit, there goes my day, lost to an ear-worm...

Comment: Well, I was hoping this meant that the Summer of Love is finally over.

Comment: @Cody hey, that's not nice. SO needs more love, not less. :D

Comment: But... 10038 is not less than three? :P

Comment: "We felt it looked out of place." That's surprising coming from the same company that put emoji in their subject lines.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We still <3 you. After many a heated internal exchange and only a few < / 3 's, we'll be re-adding the heart with a new look.

[image]

**UPDATE** Just went out to production now <3

Comment: \o/ Wohoo, nice :) <3 Stack Exchange

Comment: That looks professional while still preserving the love. Brilliant!

Comment: In b4 loads of Meta questions `What does less than three mean in my E-Mails?`

Comment: Should have just used the heart emoji   ❤️

Comment: @Pekka 웃: I'm sorry: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317919/what-is-just-3-code (or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/notification-email-from-stackoverflow-contains-3-after-zip-code if you want it to be specific to emails)