# Joining the Teams private beta in "monitor" mode?

Tags: discussion, old-teams

I just went through [The Power of Teams: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top).

The beta sign-up page seems to require creating my team. Before I do that I'd like to be able to see a list of existing teams, select and join one or more of them in "monitor" mode to better understand how the proposed concept works or could work. Can I do that now? How?

Update: this appears to be one of the intended functionality in the Teams proposal:

> Anyone can sign up and join a team. We’ve considered having a required
>   rep level to create a team, but want anyone to get involved with a
>   team if they want to. So for now, we’re starting without a
>   requirement. If chaos ensues, then we’ll revisit this area...

Comment: For now, I don't think there are teams at all. It's just a Google form collecting information about potential teams. Nothing to join yet.

Comment: Probably, if you create a team named "DanCornilescu" and delete it as soon as you enter the private beta, you'll be able to continue using, join other teams and help testing the features. However, it's not encouraged since the team is a required field.

Comment: Actually I was going to create a team for my company - if indeed the concept proves useful for it (as I suspect) it'll eventually get active as well.

Answer (score 5):

In the beta phase, creating teams will be limited to beta members (so that we — Stack Overflow the company — can handle moderation manually and observe how Teams are used).

However, you should be able to *see* Teams regardless of whether you're in the beta or not.

Regardless, feel free to sign up for the beta. We're not going to blame you if you don't create a team immediately (or ever)!