# Received a mail invitation to create a SO Careers profile but I already have one

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs, email

Today when I viewed my profile there was a new shiny blue-ish banner at the top that said something like

> We are enhancing the user profiles, here are some steps you can follow to get started

and then it asked me some questions which I answered.

Upon completion I received an email saying

> Hi Tim Castelijns
>
> Congratulations on joining the Stack Overflow community. Since you
>   indicated that you’re open to be contacted by employers you’re invited
>   to create a Stack Overflow Careers profile.
>
> Creating a profile is quick and simple. You have total control over
>   the content of your profile, whether it includes your Stack Overflow
>   answers, open source projects or any interesting books you've read.
>   Your profile will be searchable by employers who will come to you, and
>   you can use it to apply to any job posted on Stack Overflow Careers.
>
> Click here to get started
>
> Best,
>
> The Stack Overflow Careers Team

I already have a careers account though (have had it for ~2 years I believe). Maybe this can be checked before sending the mail?

Maybe this is related (probably not): every time I go to careers, I have to log in again, while on all other SE sites I am automatically logged in.

Comment: I saw that same shiny banner, thought it was odd that it was asking questions I had already filled out, and just closed it.

Comment: @sevenseacat Same, but since it was new I figured it would ask me new questions at some point. It didn't though.

Comment: I recieved the same mail, even though I have my Careers profile associated (but hidden) to my SO account...

Comment: Same thing happened to me yesterday -- including the invite at the end, which was odd. I was somewhat ambivalent about the whole thing -- I sort of felt this was the beginning of a broader "[let's push SO teams now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)" drive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oops! We *were* checking for existing profiles, among other conditions, before sending Careers invitations... but we missed some parenthesis and ended up with a `(a && b || c)`. This has been fixed and pushed to production on build rev `2015.11.11.2970`. Thanks for your report <3

Comment: Rookie mistake ;-) thanks for the fix

Comment: Yeah, I think we've all been there :)