# Can you please add a site for programs/projects feedback?

Tags: feature-request

Along many years of using the computer, I was using and trying a lot of (wonderful) programs - open source or closed source. Many times I provided feedback by posting bug reports and feature requests on various forums those programs use - and millions of computer users like me also did that. This feedback that we -the users - provide is undeniably of great help for the developers of those programs.

However, my list of accounts is growing larger and larger and every day I'm growing tried of opening another account on another web forum for providing a little bit of feedback for a program or project.

So my request is to create a website where a project team can open an account and allow Stack Overflow users to post feature requests, bug reports and questions for/about their project.

I can already post questions about any program on Stack Overflow (like "How do I change the default port for the Apache web server?") - so it's just natural to let the users also post feature requests and bug reports.

The unified platforms are winning these days. Valve's Steam gaming platform and Stack Overflow are the best examples for that. Because the people have limited time and the fact that you can use a single account to do many things greatly improves the efficiency.

In the world of computing, a lot of program feedback is not generated simply because the people don't have the time, energy and the mood to waste 5-10 minutes just to open another account on another project sub-forum.

So I am suggesting to create a simple platform for allowing the Stack Overflow users to report bugs and to post feature requests. I am convinced that Stack Overflow team surely has the resources to do that, but anyway it has to be something basic; it shouldn't require much effort. No need for advanced bug tracking system. Once the developers notice that a Stack Overflow bug report is valid, they can re-post it on their advanced bug-tracking website, and it's in their interest to do that.

A simple example: I just installed [HeidiSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeidiSQL) and the program freezes when I start it. I just can't stand to open an account on their forum, makes me sick to add one more account to my list of accounts that already contains tens if not more than one hundred of accounts.

I firmly believe that tens of thousands of projects would open an account here and the project would be wildly successful. Also, I think there are others who would be interested to help financing such an initiative, in case some extra resources are needed - entities like the [Shuttleworth Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttleworth_Foundation) and such.

Comment: We don't have _forums_ at Stack Exchange, that's your most prominent misconception!

Comment: Oh sorry! I meant to post it at StackExchange! My bad, really sorry. I've already posted it there.

Comment: Still the concept of having _forums_ is orthogonal for **any** Stack Exchange site. You're on a train-wreck here.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't sound like something that Stack Overflow should be doing.

A feedback site like this wouldn't be purelly addressing a programming audience, so the "unified platform" argument doesn't really hold unless you want a unified platform to do everything for everyone under the sun.

There's even grave doubts whether something as genuinely programmer-y as [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) is something that Stack Overflow should really be touching!

I also wouldn't be optimistic that Open Source projects would actually appreciate having another place they have to check for bug reports and such, on top of their own support channels.

A platform like Github, which also provides highly developed other services for Open Source projects, is infinitely more suited to be a place for feedback on a specific project than Stack Overflow.

Comment: First of all, I've posted it in the wrong place - and sorry again for that. The sub-site can simply limit it's scope to a programming audience. The OS projects would surely appreciate that since it would generate a lot of valuable input, most likely, even more than on their own support channels. Not all projects are hosted on GitHub or SourceFoge. Many have their own forums, greatly adding to the mess. Not everyone feels like "a pro", considering that you have to open another account in order to post a feature request. Simple non-pro users can provide great feedback.

Comment: @frostwolf if you limit the audience to programmers, then the new [teams](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1) feature does what you want, and more I think

Comment: That's great, I didn't knew about that proposal, thanks for pointing me to it. However, In order to attract the project teams to open accounts on StackExchange, I think it should offer them the feature request and bug report first. That would motivate them to come because they will see immediate benefit for doing it. I will post my opinion there, thanks again for the link. And speaking about the Documentation proposal, yes I think it's a good idea, StackExchange pulverized Experts Exchange simply because it din't limit their audience to the "elite" (genuinely programmers)-newbs are welcome too